# How is LIKE implemented?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, performance, full-text-search, pattern-matching

Can anyone explain how the LIKE operator is implemented in current database systems (e.g. MySQL or Postgres)? or point me to some references that explain it?

The naive approach would be to inspect each record, executing a regular expression or partial string match on the field of interest, but I have a feeling (hope) that these systems do something smarter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, that's pretty much what they're doing.  Now, if there is not a leading wildcard and the field is indexed, which is the usual situation, the database engine can apply the regular expression to the index.  So, for example, if you write

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name LIKE 'Cav%'
```

the database can use the index on `LAST_NAME` to find all the rows where the last name begins 'Cav'.  On the other hand, if you had something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 WHERE last_name LIKE '%av%'
```

the database would have to scan the entire table (or the entire index) and evaluate the expression against the full `LAST_NAME` value.  Obviously, that's very expensive.

Most of the better relational databases have facilities to do full-text search in a more efficient manner by constructing different sorts of indexes and text catalogs but these don't use the LIKE keyword.  For example, here's a nice article that discusses [full-text search in PostgreSQL](http://linuxgazette.net/164/sephton.html).

Comment: Oracle can use an index even with a leading percent.  If the data being searched for represents a small subset of the rows then hint can force it to use an index and make the execution faster.  See http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2009/07/how-to-tune-where-name-likebc.html.

Comment: "scan the entire table... Obviously, that's very expensive" -- that rather depends on the table ;) p.s. do you agree `LAST_NAME` be a candidate for (the first column in) the clustered index? p.p.s. to what extent does this answer assume the database system is based on contiguous storage on disk and B-tree indexes?

Answer (score 30):

In addition to what Justin Cave wrote, since **PostgreSQL 9.1** you can speed up *any* search with `LIKE` (`~~`) or `ILIKE` (`~~*`), and basic regular expression matches, too (`~`). Use the operator classes provided by the module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) with a GIN or GiST index to speed up `LIKE` expressions that are not left-anchored. To install the extension, run once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;
```

Create an index of the form:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_gin_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin (col gin_trgm_ops);
```

Or:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_col_gist_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gist (col gist_trgm_ops);
```

Creating and maintaining a [**GIN or GiST index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin.html) carries a cost, but if your table is not heavily written, this is a great feature for you.

[Depesz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1593/depesz) has an [excellent article](https://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/) in his blog about the feature.

#### GIN or GiST?

These two [quotes from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.8) should provide some guidance

> The choice between GiST and GIN indexing depends on the relative
> performance characteristics of GiST and GIN, which are discussed
> elsewhere.

(Like [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html).)

But for "nearest neighbour" type of queries with the using the distance operator `<->`:

> This can be implemented quite efficiently by GiST indexes, but not by
> GIN indexes.

Comment: Reading this I wondered whether to use GIN or GiST. According to what I read, GIN indexes are more expensive to maintain but faster to search, while a GiST index is cheaper to maintain but slower to search. This means GIN indexes should generally be used on relatively static data while GiST indexes are preferred on more heavily mutating tables.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: That's generally true, but there are exceptions to the rule. Consider the addendum above.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking about MySQL, the position of the wild-card character (%) makes a difference. If the first part of the text is specified like `where first_name like 'Sta%'`, then the DB engine will search only a smaller subset of words staring with S, then going to St, and then Sta, etc. If you do something like `where first_name like '%stan%'`, then and entire scan of the column will be required. 
You can also look into full-text indexes that also does natural language searches. [Check out the MySQL docs here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Why would it start searching "S%" when the substring is defined to 3 characters (i.e. we know the string isn't "Sr%")? Or were you assuming the DB has a prefix tree over the attributes and providing an example of traversing this tree?