# DBLINK match a value from a local table

Tags: postgresql

Am trying to run the following dblink start transaction;

```
select dblink_connect('host=remote port=5432 dbname=remote_db user=user password=pass');
insert into local_table (column1, column2 )
select * from dblink(`
    select remote_column1 ltrim(remote_column2, ''TEST'') from remote_table
       where remote_column2 ilike ''TEST%''  
) as t(column1 varchar, column2 varchar) ;
```

now the above works fine, but am encountering a challenge:- I want instead of hardcoding `TEST`, I want it to be queried from a local table so I would wish to substitute `TEST` to something like `SELECT uniq_id from some_local_table` The logic behind it is I want to get records which has prefix matching the result of `SELECT uniq_id from some_local_table` but trim the prefix when inserting to `local_table` hope someone understands me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should actually work with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT dblink_connect(
                'host=remote port=5432 dbname=remote_db user=user password=pass');


INSERT INTO local_table (column1, column2)
SELECT *
FROM   dblink((
          SELECT '
             SELECT remote_column1 ltrim(remote_column2, ''' || uniq_id || ''')
             FROM   remote_table
             WHERE  remote_column2 ILIKE ''' || uniq_id || '%''
             AND    row_counter > ' || coalesce((
                SELECT max(row_counter)
                FROM   yet_another_local_table), -1)
          FROM   some_local_table
          --WHERE <some_condition>
          LIMIT  1  -- make sure it's one row
          )
       ) AS t(column1 varchar, column2 varchar);

SELECT dblink_disconnect();
```

The meta-levels and layers of single-quotes may be a bit confusing.

This form is vulnerable to [SQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLI). Make sure nothing bad can come from `some_local_table` or use `quote_literal(uniq_id)` in place of plain `uniq_id`.

---

In reply to the comment I added a nested correlated subquery to the example. It returns a single row, so it should work fine. Could also be done by left-joining to it in the `FROM` clause.

Note that I rewrote the expression to make `COALESCE()` the outer wrapper, so the query won't fail if there are no rows `yet_another_local_table`. The way you had it would only catch the case where `max(row_counter) IS NULL`.

Probably easier to read with [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (requires Postgres 9.1+):

```
INSERT INTO local_table (column1, column2)
SELECT *
FROM   dblink(
         (SELECT format(
            'SELECT remote_column1 ltrim(remote_column2, %1$L)
             FROM   remote_table
             WHERE  remote_column2 ILIKE %2$L
             AND    row_counter > %3s'
            ,uniq_id,  uniq_id || '%'
            ,COALESCE((
               SELECT max(row_counter)
               FROM   yet_another_local_table), -1)
            )
          FROM   some_local_table
          --WHERE <some_condition>
          LIMIT  1)
   ) AS t(column1 varchar, column2 varchar);
```

Comment: @Phil: A rather unexpected collateral benefit. :) If you like `ILIKE`, you may be interested in [this related answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684).

Comment: I'm an Oracle guy & would use `REGEXP_LIKE()`. It's good knowing equivalents :)

Comment: I wanted to include another condition after `WHERE  remote_column2 ilike ''' || uniq_id || '%'''
    FROM   some_local_table` i.e  `and  row_counter>'||(select coalesce(max(row_counter),-1)
        from yet_another_local_table` how would I go about that?

Comment: @user1328181: added to my answer to cover your 2nd question.