# Indexes vs Collation vs Pattern Ops

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, collation, pattern-matching

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.
Having already read articles and answers on DBA stackexchange:

[Why would you index text_pattern_ops on a text column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53811/why-would-you-index-text-pattern-ops-on-a-text-column)

[PostgreSQL documentation: Indexes - Opclass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html)

[Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

and being aware of `EXPLAIN` command I've crossed paths with performance issues in my DB.

As mentioned in documentation and answers above, it seems that when my **database** has a collation **C**

```
db=# SHOW LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate 
------------
 C
```

I do not need to use special operator ie `text_pattern_ops` on my indexes.

I've also tested how things work in my database and it seems that I:

1. have collate C
2. have table (assume it's named as `table`) containing column named signature of type text
3. have index on that table `idx_table_sign btree (upper(signature))`
4. also have index on that table `idx_table_sign_like btree (upper(signature) text_pattern_ops)`

Now let's assume I have a row with `signature` value `I Lm 837/32`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from table WHERE upper(signature) = 'I Lm 837/32'
```

Does search using index

```
Index Scan idx_table_sign on table ... 
Index Cond: ...
```

Which is OK considering our index, but let's see this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from table WHERE upper(signature) LIKE 'I Lm 837/3%';

    Index Scan idx_table_sign_like on table ...
    Index Cond: (... ~>=~ ...) AND (... ~<~ ...)
    Filter: ... ~~ ...
```

Which seems good as well, but as I've read when I do have collation `C` i don't need to set `text_pattern_ops` indexes, so imagine this:

```
DROP INDEX idx_table_sign_like;

EXPLAIN SELECT * from table WHERE upper(signature) LIKE 'I Lm 837/3%';
```

Which only differs in operators (`~>=~` is now simply `>=` and `~<~` is `<`)

```
    Index Scan idx_table_sign_like on table ...
    Index Cond: (... >= ...) AND (... < ...)
    Filter: ... ~~ ...
```

Now, thank you for reading this and getting so far, here are questions:

1. Do I need two indexes on this column with one using `text_pattern_ops`? Doesn't collate `C` do the trick? Also, is it possible that I have a table or a column that overwrites the collation of entire database, and because of that it might have been added? If yes, please tell me how do I check that.
2. Are the operations `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` slowed by this index (imagine I have 4 columns like this in a table containing 1 million rows - main point is that those indexes need to be rebuilt (as far as I know), which may be unnecessary - **this question is about telling me whether or not queries also use this index with text_pattern_ops instead of just C collation and if that may result in lower performance - you can see the EXECUTION PLANS with that index**
3. Do queries like `select ... where upper(signature) like 'xxx%'` - left-anchored patterns use index `idx_table_sign_like` **which is totally unnecessary considering my collation which they could be using instead**? - please notice the difference in operators that planner is using depending on index (having it or not)
4. **Added after Craig Ringer answer**. In my columns I'm having text and varchar which contain **polish characters**. What does it change in my specific case? I hope this is some kind of a hint for the answerer on topic of neediness of those indexes.

These questions are very important, as my database is pretty huge **(> 1TB)** and has more than a dozen tables containing such indexes on several columns, on which inserts and updates come on a daily basis.

Comment: I'll let someone else answer this; responding to your follow up comments (on my deleted answer) will take longer than I have.

Comment: Thanks though for your effort. I'll edit my question to make it more specific about what I'm asking for.

Comment: Most experienced people read both/all sites, following tags of interest like [tag:postgresql]. You haven't got answers because your question is long and confusing, and it isn't quite clear what you want / what about the docs doesn't already explain what you need. It's also a multi-question where you try to ask a bunch of different things that aren't really all that closely related, which tends to put people off.

Comment: I will try to edit/improve my question.

Comment: Try to avoid multiple semi-related questions in a single post - "laundry lists" of questions. Keep it as short and sweet as you can while including the relevant information. If you've tried something then ask about it, explain why what you already found isn't good enough (e.g. you ask whether Pg will use a given index, when you've already clearly demonstrated that it will... so what are you asking for?). Try not to be too proscriptive and demand a specific response, people will tend to walk off - you're not paying anyone for this, after all.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, particularly the last point.

Comment: For what its worth, I think perhaps you're misunderstanding the effects of `C` collation. It ignores natural language sorting and sorts by byte order. It's generally not desirable if your DB contains human-readable text as things will sort in the wrong order as far as your language is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

consider using the citext data type available in contrib. you don't have to do this upper / lower nightmare anymore. for the regular expression type you can use gist along with gist_trgm_ops. it will boost regular expressions nicely.