# Does creating a unique constraint on a Postgres column remove the need to index it?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, unique-constraint

Does creating a unique constraint on a Postgres column remove the need to index it?

I expect that an index is automatically needed to maintain the constraint efficiently.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. A [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) is implemented with the help of a unique index -  a b-tree index with default ascending sort ordering over all involved columns. The index is created and maintained automatically, and is used for all purposes like a plain unique index by Postgres.

There is no need to create another (redundant) unique index like it, that would be a waste of resources.

Detailed explanation:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067108/939860)
- [Is unique index better than unique constraint when an index with an operator class is required](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90722/is-unique-index-better-than-unique-constraint-when-an-index-with-an-operator-cla/90810#90810)

Some rare exceptions apply for multicolumn indexes with special sort options:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)