# Postgresql get rows based on minimum value

Tags: postgresql, query, greatest-n-per-group

Having this table:

| warehouse_id | destination_id | days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

I'd like to get the `warehouse_id` and `days` **for each value** of `warehouse_id`, where the row has the minimum value of `days`, and `destination_id` matches a specific value, ordered by `days`.

For example for `destination_id` = 1

| warehouse_id | days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |

Comment: *the minimum value of days* MIN() *for destination_id = 1* WHERE *for each value of warehouse_id* GROUP BY

Comment: The best solution depends on undisclosed cardinalities. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177174/3684

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query which orders by first for `warehouse_id` and `days` then gets first record only according to `DISTINCT ON` clause

> ```
> select distinct on (warehouse_id) 
>     warehouse_id,
>     days 
>   from this_table 
>   where destination_id = 1 
>   order by warehouse_id, days
> ```
>
> ```
> warehouse_id | days
> -----------: | ---:
>            1 |    2
>            2 |    3
>            3 |    5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af1a6cc051fa22db4a7df208cf4f061e)*

Answer (score 0):

A simple aggregation like

```
select warehouse_id, min(days)
from this_table
where destination_id = 1
group by warehouse_id;
```

gives the answer in the question.