# A better way to write this query?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, performance, relational-division, postgresql-performance

I have the following schema for my database (Postgresql 10):

```
CREATE TABLE "PulledTexts" (
"Id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
"BaseText" TEXT,
"CleanText" TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE "UniqueWords" (
"Id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
"WordText" TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE "WordTexts" (
"Id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
"TextIdId" INTEGER REFERENCES "PulledTexts",
"WordIdId" INTEGER REFERENCES "UniqueWords"
);
CREATE INDEX "IX_WordTexts_TextIdId" ON "WordTexts" ("TextIdId");
CREATE INDEX "IX_WordTexts_WordIdId" ON "WordTexts" ("WordIdId");
```

Some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO public."PulledTexts" ("Id", "BaseText", "CleanText") VALUES
(1, 'automate business audit', null),
(2, 'audit trial', null),
(3, 'trial', null),
(4, 'audit', null),
(5, 'fresh report', null),
(6, 'fresh audit', null),
(7, 'automate this script', null),
(8, 'im trying here', null),
(9, 'automate this business', null),
(10, 'lateral', null);

INSERT INTO public."UniqueWords" ("Id", "WordText") VALUES
(1, 'trial'),
(2, 'audit'),
(3, 'creation'),
(4, 'business'),
(5, 'automate');

INSERT INTO public."WordTexts" ("Id", "TextIdId", "WordIdId") VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 4),
(3, 1, 5),
(4, 2, 1),
(5, 3, 1),
(6, 4, 2),
(7, 6, 2),
(8, 7, 5),
(9, 9, 4),
(10, 9, 5),
(11, 2, 2);
```

The database itself is created through Entity framework migration for now.

I would like to know if there's a better, specifically more performance efficient way of writing this query because the `WordTexts` table will contain hundreds of thousands of records and eventually millions. I am also open to going a NoSql route if that would be more efficient for these kinds of queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM "PulledTexts"
WHERE "Id" IN (
 SELECT "TextIdId"
 FROM "WordTexts" AS "wordTexts"
 LEFT JOIN "UniqueWords" AS "wordTexts.WordId" ON "wordTexts"."WordIdId" = "wordTexts.WordId"."Id"
 WHERE "wordTexts.WordId"."WordText" = 'automate'

 OR "TextIdId" IN (
  SELECT "TextIdId" and1
  from "WordTexts" AS "wordTexts"
  LEFT JOIN "UniqueWords" AS "wordTexts.WordId" ON "wordTexts"."WordIdId" = "wordTexts.WordId"."Id"
  where "wordTexts.WordId"."WordText" = 'audit' INTERSECT

  SELECT "TextIdId" and2
  from "WordTexts" AS "wordTexts"
  LEFT JOIN "UniqueWords" AS "wordTexts.WordId" ON "wordTexts"."WordIdId" = "wordTexts.WordId"."Id"
  WHERE "wordTexts.WordId"."WordText" = 'trial'
 )
);
```

At a high level, this query is supposed to return PulledTexts whose IDs match those returned by the subqueries. The subqueries are simply meant to return the list of IDs of PulledTexts that contain lets say `('audit' AND 'trial') OR 'automate'` from the UniqueWords table. This is exactly what the example query I gave does. The WordTexts table is a simple mapping of UniqueWord to PulledText.

Comment: See if that update helps you out a bit more towards getting what you want @H.Rahimy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While your query is valid, there is *a lot* I would differently.

1. Don't use CaMeL-case names in Postgres if it can be avoided. Your unnamed entity framework may force this nonsense upon you, but I don't want to deal with the double-quote mess, so I tested with your schema after removing all double-quotes - effectively making all identifiers lower-cased.

   - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)
2. Don't use illegible or illegal column and table aliases (like `"wordTexts.WordId"`). That's a matter of taste and style (and sanity), but you also omitted the keyword `AS` where you should *not* and kept it where you could omit it.

   - [Date column arithmetic in PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543614/939860)
3. I also formatted some more to make it easier for me to grok the query. That last part is totally optional. But use *some* consistent formatting style.

Arriving at *this*:

```
SELECT *
FROM   PulledTexts
WHERE  Id IN (
   SELECT w.TextIdId
   FROM   WordTexts w  -- AS can be omitted for table alias
   LEFT   JOIN UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id  -- LEFT JOIN might be necessary here
   WHERE  u.WordText = 'automate'
   OR     w.TextIdId IN (
      SELECT w.TextIdId  -- AS and1 -- column alias only documentation here, not visible
      FROM   WordTexts w
      JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id  -- LEFT JOIN misleading here
      WHERE  u.WordText = 'audit'

      INTERSECT
      SELECT w.TextIdId  -- AS and2  -- but don't omit AS for column alias
      FROM   WordTexts w
      JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id
      WHERE  u.WordText = 'trial'
      )
   );
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT w.TextIdId AS Id
   FROM   WordTexts   w
   JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id  -- now we don't need LEFT any more
   WHERE  u.WordText = 'automate'

   UNION
   SELECT w.TextIdId
   FROM   WordTexts w
   JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id
   WHERE  u.WordText = 'audit'

   INTERSECT
   SELECT w.TextIdId
   FROM   WordTexts w
   JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id
   WHERE  u.WordText = 'trial'
   ) w
JOIN   PulledTexts p USING (Id)
```

We do not need additional parentheses because, [according to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#sql-intersect):

> `INTERSECT` binds more tightly than `UNION`. That is, `A UNION B INTERSECT C` will be read as `A UNION (B INTERSECT C)`.

But this will be faster when replacing *multiple* intersected subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT w.TextIdId AS Id
   FROM   WordTexts   w
   JOIN   UniqueWords u ON w.WordIdId = u.Id
   WHERE  u.WordText = 'automate'

   UNION
   SELECT TextIdId
   FROM   WordTexts w1
   JOIN   WordTexts w2 USING (TextIdId)
   WHERE  w1.WordIdId = (SELECT Id FROM UniqueWords WHERE WordText = 'audit')
   AND    w2.WordIdId = (SELECT Id FROM UniqueWords WHERE WordText = 'trial')
   ) w
JOIN   PulledTexts p USING (Id)
```

The `INTERSECT` part can be cast as *relational division* problem. Explanation in this related answer from just yesterday:

- [Counting with multiple joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115212/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f2ebd76c4f6359d64c541f700528f90a)*

Most important for performance is to have the right **indexes**. You probably should have a **`UNIQUE` constraint** on `(WordIdId, TextIdId)` in table `WordTexts`, which implements the currently missing index on those two columns in *this* order.

- [Does creating a unique constraint on a Postgres column remove the need to index it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132929/does-creating-a-unique-constraint-on-a-postgres-column-remove-the-need-to-index/132930#132930)

Answer (score 0):

## [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)

What you're doing is creating a normalized relational Full Text Search. That seems problematic and wasteful. PostgreSQL (and most other professional databases) [have the functionality to handle all of this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)..

```
SELECT txt, to_tsvector(txt)
FROM ( VALUES
    ( 'automate business audit' ),
    ( 'audit trial' ),
    ( 'trial' ),
    ( 'audit' ),
    ( 'fresh report' ),
    ( 'fresh audit' ),
    ( 'automate this script' ),
    ( 'im trying here' ),
    ( 'automate this business' ),
    ( 'lateral' )
) AS t(txt);

           txt           |         to_tsvector          
-------------------------+------------------------------
 automate business audit | 'audit':3 'autom':1 'busi':2
 audit trial             | 'audit':1 'trial':2
 trial                   | 'trial':1
 audit                   | 'audit':1
 fresh report            | 'fresh':1 'report':2
 fresh audit             | 'audit':2 'fresh':1
 automate this script    | 'autom':1 'script':3
 im trying here          | 'im':1 'tri':2
 automate this business  | 'autom':1 'busi':3
 lateral                 | 'later':1
```

You can see here that not all of these stems make sense. That's because we're using the default algorithmic stemmer Snowball. The important thing here is you can search these terms effectively because the queries undergo the same stemming: both queries and input get reduced to lexemes. If you need something more accurate that doesn't reduce to `later` or `autom` then Hunspell can take you the full distance: it'll be *massively* faster than your method, but slower then the Snowball method.

Using Full Text Search can drastically simplify your schema too. If you don't actually need the internal mechanisms, you can just

```
CREATE TABLE pulledtext (
  id        int   GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  basetext  text
);
CREATE INDEX ON pulledtext ( to_tsvector('english', basetext) );

## Index search like this,
SELECT *
FROM pulledtext
WHERE to_tsvector('english', basetext) @@ to_tsquery('english', search_term');
```

There is also a `to_tsquery` that supports conditionals. It takes the exact form you used except `&` and `|` instead of `AND` and `OR` . ;)

```
SELECT to_tsquery('english', $$( 'audit' & 'trial' ) | 'automate'$$ );
         to_tsquery          
-----------------------------
 'audit' & 'trial' | 'autom'
(1 row)
```

Converting that into a query -- it'll also work on the index.

```
SELECT *
FROM pulledtext
WHERE to_tsvector('english', basetext) @@ to_tsquery(
  'english',
   $$('audit' & 'trial') | 'automate'$$
);
 id |        basetext         
----+-------------------------
  1 | automate business audit
  2 | audit trial
  7 | automate this script
  9 | automate this business
(4 rows)
```

On naming, and not using double-quotes, I agree with all the advice given Erwin's answer.