# How can one optimize a query involving a sort and a LIKE?

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
    *
FROM
    "Users" AS "User"
WHERE
    "User"."name" LIKE 'garr%'
AND "User"."id" NOT IN (2449214)
AND "User"."hellbanned" IS NULL
AND "User"."hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL
ORDER BY
    "followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 3;
```

Which yields:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..3662.92 rows=3 width=1711) (actual time=181.935..2158.898 rows=3 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using users_search_followercount_index on "Users" "User"  (cost=0.43..280791.25 rows=230 width=1711) (actual time=181.933..2158.891 rows=3 loops=1)
        Filter: (((name)::text ~~ 'garr%'::text) AND (id <> 2449214))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 29434
Total runtime: 2158.951 ms
```

The index used is the most optimal I could build:

```
CREATE INDEX users_search_followercount_index ON "Users" ("followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST) WHERE "hellbanned" IS NULL AND "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL;
```

I also tried these:

```
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_name_unique_index ON "Users" ("name");
-- CREATE INDEX users_followerCount_index ON "Users" ("followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST);
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_search_name_followercount_unique_index ON "Users" ("name", "followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST) WHERE "hellbanned" IS NULL AND "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL; -- N/A
-- CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_search_followercount_name_unique_index ON "Users" ("followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST, "name") WHERE "hellbanned" IS NULL AND "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL; -- 5422
-- CREATE INDEX users_name_unique_index ON "Users" ("name") WHERE "hellbanned" IS NULL AND "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL; -- 5422
```

But none speed it up.

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your hardware, it look like.  2 seconds for an index scan on less than 30k rows sounds really bad.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm running Amazon RDS with a T2 Medium. Everything is below 20% usage bug my Freeable Memory is ~0-3GB, which could be why this takes so long.

Comment: A question for performance optimization needs to provide more information. Instructions in the tag info for [\[postgresql-performance\]](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: I agree with dezso,  may be something seriously wrong with your hardware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index attempts are still futile, since the predicate

```
u."name" LIKE 'garr%'
```

is obviously the most selective one but cannot use a basic (default) b-tree index unless you are operating with the "C" locale (which would be uncommon).

```
SELECT *
FROM   "Users"
WHERE  name LIKE 'garr%'
AND    id <> 2449214
AND    hellbanned IS NULL
AND    "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL
ORDER  BY "followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  3;
```

There are several options (also depending on the missing table definition and other information), this index should work:

```
CREATE INDEX "Users_whatever_idx"
ON     "Users" (name text_pattern_ops, "followerCount" DESC NULLS LAST) 
WHERE  hellbanned IS NULL
AND   "hellbanPostsAfterDate" IS NULL;
```

The conditions on `hellbanned` and `"hellbanPostsAfterDate"` are only useful if they exclude more than a few rows. Else, a complete index might be the better choice, since it can be used for more different queries.

Also, there is a chance the second column in the index `"followerCount"` won't help, since there are typically multiple different matches for the first and Postgres has to sort after all. Test a couple of typical queries with and without the second column in the index.

Details for indexes and pattern matching, including an explanation for the operator class `text_pattern_ops`:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Aside: My standing advise is to use unquoted, legal, lower-case identifiers exclusively in Postgres.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, the identifier mismatch is my fault, I tried to remove all the double quotes and other noise but did only half of the work.  I rolled my change back.

Comment: @dezso: Ah, I see. Adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Amazing, down to 0.127ms!

Comment: @Garrett: Nice, factor 20k. :) Did you try with and / or without `"followerCount"` as second column in the index?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you will try to use nested query...

```
select * from (SELECT
    *
FROM
    Users AS u
WHERE
    u."name" LIKE 'garr%'
AND u.id NOT IN (2449214)
) AS u 
WHERE  u.hellbanned IS NULL
AND u.hellbanPostsAfterDate IS NULL
ORDER BY
    followerCount DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: How will this help with the issue?