# Get count estimates from pg_class.reltuples for given conditions

Tags: postgresql, index, count

Is it possible to query the `reltuples` column for a given table with additional conditions like `table.name LIKE 'hello%'`?

Currently on my bigger tables the `SELECT count(*)` query takes long and I wouldn't need an exact count. So I wanted to know if it's possible to add `WHERE` clauses to the `reltuples` as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not out of the box. But you can achieve it with a ...

#### [Partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html)

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_name_hello_idx ON tbl(tbl_id) WHERE name LIKE 'hello%';

SELECT reltuples
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'tbl_name_hello_idx'::regclass;  -- or schema-qualify table name
```

The actual index column (`tbl_id` in the example) is irrelevant (unless you have additional use for the index). Best pick a small column that is never changed: a `serial` PK column would be a perfect candidate. Or you could use a constant (which defeats additional purposes of that index):

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_name_hello_idx ON tbl((1)) WHERE name LIKE 'hello%';
```

Every index has its own entry in `pg_class` and its own `reltuples` count. [The documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

> `reltuples` ...
> Number of rows in the table. This is only an
> estimate used by the planner. It is updated by `VACUUM`, `ANALYZE`, and a
> few DDL commands such as `CREATE INDEX`.

Hence, a partial index can be (ab-)used to get count estimates for any set of predicates, updated by `autovacuum` automatically. Or maybe you already have the index because you need it anyway?

This might actually be a very clever idea. But you have to weigh cost and benefits: the partial index is small for a ***rare*** condition, but the cost gets bigger for a ***common*** condition. And while keeping the statistics up to date is comparatively cheap, it's not free of cost.

Related:

- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/index-that-is-not-used-yet-influences-query)
- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)

#### [`TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) in Postgres 9.5+

You will love the new feature in the upcoming Postgres 9.5, which only looks at a random sample of n % of blocks in the table to get a quick estimate. Example for 1 %:

```
SELECT 100 * count(*) AS estimate
FROM   tbl TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (1)
WHERE  name LIKE 'hello%';
```

Details in the answer already linked above:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)

#### Alternative for given example

For the given example `name LIKE 'hello%'` you could get very fast ***exact*** results using the right index anyway:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_name_text_pattern_idx ON tbl(name text_pattern_ops);
```

See:

- [How can one optimize a query involving a sort and a LIKE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91468/how-can-one-optimize-a-query-involving-a-sort-and-a-like/91537#91537)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Comment: Hey thanks for your explanation! That was really really great.
Currently I really don't know what to do, since Triggers wouldn't work since I basically have a list where a User could insert search conditions and then he gets like 5 Badges with Counts (Open Orders, Closed Orders, etc...) and it could get really slow especially based on the fact that mostly NO condition is hit so I run like a lot of slow queries.

Comment: btw I also thought of making a mat view which will be updated in the background, but I don't know if that is a good idea in particular.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt: Whether a MV can be useful depends on the range of possible queries.

Comment: it's definitly useful, I 'could' have like 5-6 LIKE's on a query, I also could have only one, etc. Also mostly I need an INNER JOIN over 5-6 Tables. Which is odd and the Background refresh works brilliantly.
P.S.: Before we used Elasticsearch to do the lists but however Elasticsearch was unpredicatble in some manners. We will still use Elasticsearch for that, but we will use Postgres Views/Mat Views to have a Backup solution.

Answer (score 3):

You've already been giving some excellent advice on how to create indexes to get the estimate more efficiently.  But if you don't want to create another index to do that, another approach is to ask `PostgreSQL` to do the estimate for you.

If you want an estimate of a query like:

```
select count(*) from foo where bar like 'Hello%';
```

What you can do instead is execute:

```
explain select * from foo where bar like 'Hello%';
```

The first row returned by this query will look like:

```
Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..52853.94 rows=1520803 width=256)
```

And you can parse out the number after 'rows='

This is the estimate that `PostgreSQL` uses for its own internal planning, and it incorporates all the information which `PostgreSQL` knows how to incorporate.

Comment: of course I know how that works, but it's slow I NEED to migrate away that's why I'm asking...

Comment: Have you tried it?  `EXPLAIN` is not slow.

Comment: This is kind of brilliant.  I wish there was an actual query that would give you the estimated rows that PG uses for the query plan but as a finger-in-the-air estimate this is great.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use it. See [this page in the postgresql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/row-estimation-examples.html) as example.

But take into account that there are several ways to count / estimate the rows in a table. See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745/930271) for a couple of different ways.

Using your LIKE clause as example, and ignoring "system tables" you can build this kind of query:

```
SELECT
  nspname AS schemaname, relname as tablename, reltuples
FROM
  pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' AND
  relname LIKE 'hello%'
ORDER BY reltuples DESC;
```

Comment: ow, that's nice, but not what i wanted, i meant not LIKE on the table name I meant like on table data Like hello has a field name which could contain 'hello%'

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's right. I did not understand your question correctly