# Operator "~<~" uses varchar_pattern_ops index while normal ORDER BY clause doesn't?

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, order-by, collation, system-tables

Let's say I have a table with  1 000 000  records.
Structure of table is:

```
create table individual (     
  id serial primary key,
  surname varchar(128),
  "name" varchar(128),
  patronymic varchar(128),
  birth_dt date
)
```

I create a composite index.

INDEX 1

```
create index on individual using btree (upper(surname) varchar_pattern_ops
  , upper("name") varchar_pattern_ops, patronymic varchar_pattern_ops, birth_dt);
```

Docs state that `varchar_pattern_ops` should be applied when using `LIKE` or pattern match in query. Conclusion: this index will not be used in query below, even it gets only 10 row from 1 000 000.

QUERY 1

```
select * from individual
order by upper(surname), upper("name"), upper(patronymic), birth_dt limit 10;
```

and even more, docs recommends to create an index without `varchar_pattern_ops` as well.

INDEX 2

```
create index on individual using btree
(upper(surname), upper("name"), upper(patronimyc), birth_dt);
```

Then a query using `LIMIT` will use this index.

I found a cheat to force Postgres to use first index on Postgres users forum. It is operator `~<~`.

QUERY 2

```
select * from individual
order by upper(surname) using ~<~
       , upper("name") using ~<~
       , upper(patronymic) using ~<~
       , birth_dt limit 100;
```

In this case **INDEX 1** will be used even if **INDEX 2** doesn't exists. I tried to investigate to discover why it happens, but failed.

There are some system tables like `pg_operator`, which (I think) link operator `~<~` to some functions that most probably uses `LIKE` or regular expressions.

I ran **QUERY 1** and **QUERY 2** a few times and compared result manually. It looks like operator `~<~` gives correct result, but I didn't risk anything and just create a normal index anyway.

I am still interested how the Postgres planner decides which index to use index where it meets the operator `~<~` in **QUERY 1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This revolves around **`COLLATION`** rules. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#AEN35188)

> The `C` and `POSIX` collations both specify "traditional C" behavior,
> in which only the ASCII letters "`A`" through "`Z`" are treated as
> letters, and **sorting is done strictly by character code byte values**.

Bold emphasis mine. These internal operators:

`~<~`, `~<=~`, `~>=~`, `~>~`

are members of the operator classes `text_pattern_ops`, `varchar_pattern_ops` and `bpchar_pattern_ops` which *ignore* current collation rules and default to "traditional C" behavior. [Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html)

> The difference from the default operator classes is that the values
> are compared strictly character by character rather than according to
> the locale-specific collation rules.

That's why they can use your first index, while their locale-aware equivalents

`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`

would need the second (using the default operator class).

**`ORDER BY`** defaults to the current collation rules. Unless you happen to work with the "C" collation the second set of operators is used for sorting, which can only use indexes with a matching collation (default btree indexes).

Notably, pattern-matching generally relies on "traditional C" behavior, that's why a left anchored `LIKE` match can use a `_patern_ops` index with a non-C locale, but not a default index. Compare (last chapter):

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

In Postgres **9.1+** you can force a selected sort order with `COLLATE "locale_name"` (the locale has to be available in your system!). So if you run your query with **`COLLATE "C"`** (which is a much better option than the *evil hack* `using ~<~`) , it *can* use the `_pattern_ops` index:

```
SELECT * FROM individual
ORDER  BY upper(surname) COLLATE "C"
        , upper("name") COLLATE "C"
        , upper(patronymic) COLLATE "C"
        , birth_dt
LIMIT  100;
```

Results ***are*** different. Try with non-ASCII letters like `ö`,  `é`, etc. Those typically sort depending on your current collation rules, while letters `a`-`z` typically sort the same in all locales.

Comment: I got the idea. I have collation en_US.UTF-8. Since Cyrillic alphabet order(human being correct order) match  order of hex values of UTF-8 symbols, postgres will sort Cyrillic symbols properly. That's why i didn't notice difference. It almost match, except single symbol 'Ё' which is rarely used nowadays, and wasn't in my data-set.