# 'ERROR: text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist' during CREATE INDEX?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, functions, unaccent

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3 on Mac OS X Yosemite.

I try to create an unaccent lowercase trigram index. To achieve it I did this:

```
mydb=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm SCHEMA public VERSION "1.1"; 
       CREATE EXTENSION unaccent SCHEMA public; 
       ALTER FUNCTION unaccent(text) IMMUTABLE;
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
ALTER FUNCTION
```

Then I tried to create the index:

```
mydb=# CREATE INDEX author_label_hun_gin_trgm ON address 
       USING gin (public.unaccent(lower(label_hun)) gin_trgm_ops);
ERROR:  text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist
```

... and got this error. If I try to list the available text search dictionaries the `unaccent` dictionary seems to be there:

```
mydb=# \dFd
                             List of text search dictionaries
   Schema   |      Name       |                        Description                        
------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 pg_catalog | danish_stem     | snowball stemmer for danish language
 pg_catalog | dutch_stem      | snowball stemmer for dutch language
 pg_catalog | english_stem    | snowball stemmer for english language
 pg_catalog | finnish_stem    | snowball stemmer for finnish language
 pg_catalog | french_stem     | snowball stemmer for french language
 pg_catalog | german_stem     | snowball stemmer for german language
 pg_catalog | hungarian_stem  | snowball stemmer for hungarian language
 pg_catalog | italian_stem    | snowball stemmer for italian language
 pg_catalog | norwegian_stem  | snowball stemmer for norwegian language
 pg_catalog | portuguese_stem | snowball stemmer for portuguese language
 pg_catalog | romanian_stem   | snowball stemmer for romanian language
 pg_catalog | russian_stem    | snowball stemmer for russian language
 pg_catalog | simple          | simple dictionary: just lower case and check for stopword
 pg_catalog | spanish_stem    | snowball stemmer for spanish language
 pg_catalog | swedish_stem    | snowball stemmer for swedish language
 pg_catalog | turkish_stem    | snowball stemmer for turkish language
 public     | unaccent        |
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue but the index creation worked.

Comment: Is the "public" schema mapped in your `search_path`? Besides of that, I highly recommend you not executing that `ALTER FUNCTION`, create your own SQL `IMMUTABLE` function and wrap the `unaccent` call on it, this will help on upgrades.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Do not** alter the original function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION unaccent(text) IMMUTABLE;
```

I recommend this alternative approach to get an `IMMUTABLE` `unaccent()` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT public.unaccent('public.unaccent', $1)  -- schema-qualify function and dictionary
$func$;
```

Use that function for the expression index and in all queries. Detailed explanation:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

... which also solves any possible issues with the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777): The fact that you had to schema-qualify `public.unaccent()` in your index definition suggests that you might not have `public` in your `search_path`.

Then, your index can be:

```
CREATE INDEX author_label_hun_gin_trgm ON address 
USING gin (f_unaccent(label_hun) gin_trgm_ops);
```

I did *not* include `lower()`. You *can*, but trigram indexes support case insensitive patterns out of the box:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

#### Troubleshooting

If you are running all of this in the same session with the same `search_path` and one call works while the next reports `function ... does not exist`, then something is seriously broken in your database.

First make sure you are testing with a valid `search_path` setting:

```
SHOW search_path
```

See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

If you diagnose breakage, switch into alarm mode and take all the necessary steps to avoid data loss (like drawing a backup before you do anything else).

A broken index for the system table `pg_proc` might be the cause. To [reindex](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-reindexdb.html) all system tables from the shell:

```sh
reindexdb [connection-option...] --system mydb
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I actually tried to use "public.unaccent" to make sure it really searches in he public shcema. But it should have worked with pure unaccent() as well.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion, I could create a new f_unaccent function, use it with a simple select(), however, when I try to use it in the create index I get

# CREATE INDEX author_label_hun_gin_trgm ON address USING gin (f_unaccent(label_hun) gin_trgm_ops);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ERROR:  function unaccent(unknown, text) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT unaccent('unaccent', $1)
               ^

Comment: @BalázsE.Pataki: I added a chapter for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you, Erwin! My database was imported from an sql dump. I re-imported it in a new database and now I can create the trigram index without any problem. I couldn't figure out what went wrong with my original import, though.