# PostgreSQL translate special characters?

Tags: postgresql, unaccent

**Description:**

PostgreSQL 9.3

String: **`'ì ằ ú ề'`**

Desired Result:  **`'i a u e'`**

My code:

```
select translate ('ì ằ ú ề', 'ìằúề', 'iaue') ; -- it works. Result: i a u e
```

**Question:**

If I use it this way, I have to define a manual translation between 'ìằúề' and 'iaue'. Is there a better solution?

Ref: [PG Document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: This looks useful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`unaccent()`** provided by the [**additional module unaccent**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html).
Details:

- ['ERROR: text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist' during CREATE INDEX?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97307/error-text-search-dictionary-unaccent-does-not-exist-during-create-index/97330#97330)
- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)
- [Postgres accent insensitive LIKE search in Rails 3.1 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9269859/939860)

[Substantial improvements went into **Postgres 9.5**:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/release-9-5.html#AEN126896)

> - Allow empty replacement strings in unaccent (Mohammad Alhashash)
>
>   This is useful in languages where diacritic signs are represented as
>     separate characters.
> - Allow multicharacter source strings in unaccent (Tom Lane)
>
>   This could be useful in languages where diacritic signs are
>     represented as separate characters. It also allows more complex
>     unaccent dictionaries.

#### Custom rules

If you edit the default rules (like you commented) any updates (or new compilations if you compile yourself) will overwrite your manual changes. Be sure to make a backup of *both* the original *and* your edited ruleset immediately.

The [`unaccent()` function is *overloaded*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/unaccent.html#AEN172941). While the simple form uses the default dictionary `'unaccent'`:

```
SELECT unaccent('ì ằ ú ề');
```

You can chose a separate dictionary with the 2-parameter form:

```
SELECT unaccent('my_dictionary', 'ì ằ ú ề');
```

I would consider *not* to alter the default ruleset ([like instructed in the link in your comment](https://gist.github.com/jfragoulis/9914900)), but install your ruleset additionally under a custom name. This way you keep the default behavior, which receives all updates automatically, and you can clearly see in your code where you apply your alternative / extended ruleset. Follow [instructions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html) or consider [this blog](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/08/the-un-unaccentable-character.html).

And consider my [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860) for use in indexes or other contexts where you need the function to be immutable.

Comment: Thanks. I edited "unaccent.rules" (https://gist.github.com/jfragoulis/9914900) to add my rules.

Comment: @Luan: Thanks for sharing. Consider the added parts above.