# SQL regex PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, string, like, regex

Let's consider a table like that:

```
id |            name
 1 | This is a test sentence
 2 | is a sentence TeST
 3 | This a IS test sentence
 4 | iS a tEst sentence tHis
 5 | This a test sentence is
```

How could I achieve to get all the rows, searching for "is a sentence test"?

I am using:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name ILIKE '%is%' AND name ILIKE '%a%' AND name ILIKE '%sentence%' AND name ILIKE '%test%'
```

But that doesn't seem to be the best approach.

Comment: Try posix regex: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: "searching for" does not define the search conditions you desire. Exact string match? Complete, leading, trailing? Case sensitive? Fuzzy? An exact question is 50 % of the solution. And always disclose your version of Postgres and the exact table definition showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Overview of available tools: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696

Comment: Wow, I just read @ErwinBrandstetter's comment and looked at the code at the code you had scrolling off the screen. Is this supposed to have all the words? And you're including "is" (a stop word)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you use a split_to_array function to put your strings in to arrays (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html) and then you can compare them.  Postgres has a cool function to check if one array contains another.  More info on Postgres arrays here:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html

Table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE stringchecks
(
    id serial,
    name varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO stringchecks (name) VALUES ('This is a test sentence');
INSERT INTO stringchecks (name) VALUES  ('is a sentence TeST');
INSERT INTO stringchecks (name) VALUES ('This a IS test sentence');
INSERT INTO stringchecks (name) VALUES ('iS a tEst sentence tHis');
INSERT INTO stringchecks (name) VALUES ('This a test sentence is');
```

Checking for matches you have two options.  You can use regexp_split_to_array:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    regexp_split_to_array(lower(name), E'\\s+') @> 
       regexp_split_to_array(lower('is a sentence test'), E'\\s+') 
FROM stringchecks;
```

Or you can use string_to_array:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    string_to_array(lower(name), ' ') @> 
       string_to_array(lower('is a sentence test'), ' ')
FROM stringchecks;
```

In this case because it's a simple delimiter it will be faster to use string_to_array. http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/370-regexp_split_to_table-and-string_to_array-unnest-performance.html

Comment: indiri, that is taking very long with 70000 itens table. any tips to improve it? I run that query for each row of that table.

Comment: @Roots Since it's a simple delimiter you can use string_to_array instead of regexp_split_to_array to speed it up.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have `LIKE` and `ILIKE` and `~` and `~*`. This covers the SQL-LIKE conditionals and the more beefy and more [powerful regex-like](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) features.

```
SELECT
 s,
 s LIKE '%is a sentence test%' as "like",
 s ILIKE '%is a sentence test%' AS "ilike",
 s ~ '.*is a sentence test.*' AS "~",
 s ~* '.*is a sentence test.*' AS "~*"
FROM ( VALUES
 ( 'This is a test sentence' ),
 ( 'is a sentence TeST' ),
 ( 'This a IS test sentence' ),
 ( 'iS a tEst sentence tHis' ),
 ( 'This a test sentence is' )
) AS t(s);

            s            | like | ilike | ~ | ~* 
-------------------------+------+-------+---+----
 This is a test sentence | f    | f     | f | f
 is a sentence TeST      | f    | t     | f | t
 This a IS test sentence | f    | f     | f | f
 iS a tEst sentence tHis | f    | f     | f | f
 This a test sentence is | f    | f     | f | f
(5 rows)
```

You're not using any advanced regex powers, so I'd go with `LIKE`, or `ILIKE`.