# How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I have to search for hyphenated words like 'good-morning', 'good-evening', etc.

My query is:

```
select id, ts_headline(content,
                       to_tsquery('english','good-morning'),
                       'HighlightAll=true MaxFragments=100 FragmentDelimiter=$') 
from table 
where ts_content @@ to_tsquery('english','good-morning');
```

When executing this query I also get results of *'good'* and *'morning'* separately. But I want exactly matching words and fragments.
(For `ts_content` I used the same default config `english` to create the `tsvector`.)

How can I search such hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?

Comment: Assuming you run at least Postgres 9.6? (Please *always* declare your version of Postgres.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key word here is ***phrase search***, introduced with **Postgres 9.6**.

Use the ["FOLLOWED BY" operator **`<->`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-OPERATORS-TABLE) or [one of the related `<N>` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY). Or better yet, use the function `phraseto_tsquery()` to generate your `tsquery`.
[Quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), it ...

> produces `tsquery` that searches for a phrase, ignoring punctuation

[And:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES)

> `phraseto_tsquery` behaves much like `plainto_tsquery`, except that it
> inserts the `<->` (FOLLOWED BY) operator between surviving words instead
> of the `&` (AND) operator. Also, stop words are not simply discarded,
> but are accounted for by inserting `<N>` operators rather than `<->`
> operators. This function is useful when searching for exact lexeme
> sequences, since the FOLLOWED BY operators check lexeme order not just
> the presence of all the lexemes.

Your query would work like this:

```
select id
     , ts_headline(content, phraseto_tsquery('english', 'good-morning')
                          , 'HighlightAll=true MaxFragments=100 FragmentDelimiter=$') 
from   tbl 
where  ts_content @@ phraseto_tsquery('english','good-morning');
```

`phraseto_tsquery('english', 'good-morning')` generates this `tsquery`:

```
'good-morn' <-> 'good' <-> 'morn'
```

Since "good-morning" is identified as `asciihword` (hyphenated ASCII word), the stemmed complete word is added before the components. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-parsers.html)

> It is possible for the parser to produce overlapping tokens from the
> same piece of text. As an example, a hyphenated word will be reported
> both as the entire word and as each component: *(followed by an example)*

`to_tsvector()` basically does the same on the other end, so everything matches up. This allows for fine-grained options with hyphenated words. The above only finds "good-morning" with a hyphen (or variants stemming to the same). To find all strings with "good" followed by "morn" (or variants stemming to the same) use `phraseto_tsquery('english','good morning')` generating this tsquery: `'good' <-> 'morn'`

OTOH, you can enforce ***exact matches*** by adding another filter like:

```
...
AND content ~* 'good-morning'  -- case insensitive regexp match
```

Or:

```
...
AND content ILIKE '%good-morning%'
```

Seems a bit redundant to the human eye, but this way you get ***fast*** full text index support *and* ***exact*** matches.

The latter is mostly equivalent, but different (fewer) characters have special meaning in the `LIKE` pattern and might need escaping. Related:

- [PostgreSQL: Regular Expression escape function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Example to demonstrate the operator `<N>`:

`phraseto_tsquery('english', 'Juliet and the Licks')` generates this `tsquery`:

```
'juliet' <3> 'lick'
```

`<3>` meaning that `lick` must be the third lexeme after `juliet`.

Comment: Query: 
`select id
     , ts_headline(content, phraseto_tsquery('english', 'rhus-t')
                          , 'HighlightAll=true MaxFragments=100 FragmentDelimiter=$') 
from   vqbooks 
where  ts_content @@ phraseto_tsquery('english','rhus-t');`

result:
**" Lyss..,, Puls., <b>Rhus</b>-t., Sabad., "** 
 and 
**" 'infant may have a <b>Rhus</b> toxicodendron picture. (NB: <b>Rhus</b>-t desires milk)** 

I don't want to highlight 
**have a <b>Rhus</b> toxicodendron"**.  
 I want only first fragment to be highlighted.

Comment: @user3098231: A small setting for the [option `MaxFragments`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE) might help some. But I am afraid that phrase search is not currently supported well in `ts_headline()`. A bug has been reported. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/204856/3684

Comment: `phraseto_tsquery('english', 'good-morning')` produces `'good-morn' <-> 'good' <-> 'morn'`, not `'good' <-> 'morn'`. How are you getting this result? (I'm on Postgres 10, windows)

Comment: @dtheodor: Good catch. I rectified the error and added proper information.