# ts_headline() not highlighting properly for <-> operator

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-10

**`ts_headline()`** does not seem to highlight the input text in a way that respects the `<->` operator.

The following query:

```
SELECT ts_headline('English','This Commercial Bank does not have any Equity in Europe but European Commercial Bank does', 
                    phraseto_tsquery('English','European Commercial Bank')::tsquery);
```

returns the following as output:

```
This <b>Commercial</b> <b>Bank</b> does not have any Equity in Europe but <b>European</b> <b>Commercial</b> <b>Bank</b> does
```

This highlights the words *Commercial* and *Bank* separately in addition to the phrase *European Commercial Bank*.

The expected output would be:

```
This Commercial Bank does not have any Equity in Europe but <b>European</b> <b>Commercial</b> <b>Bank</b> does
```

Which only highlights *European Commercial Bank* due to the **<->** operators inserted by `phraseto_tsquery()`.

I am using Postgres 10.3 on Linux x64. Any suggestions or solutions to this problem?

[I reported a bug.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/152461454026.19805.6310947081647212894%40wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: I *think* that's a shortcoming of `ts_headline()`, which has not been extended to cover the new phrase search in pg 9.6. Ah, I see you filed a bug report - which should be mentioned in your question: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/152461454026.19805.6310947081647212894%40wrigleys.postgresql.org

Answer (score 1):

I am writing an extension that improves the `ts_headline` functionality to correctly highlight matching phrases with a single tag, while not highlighting partial matches. The extension in available at https://github.com/thevermeer/pg_ts_semantic_headline and is intended to replace `ts_headline` directly.

Usage:

```
SELECT ts_semantic_headline('English','This Commercial Bank does not have any Equity in Europe but European Commercial Bank does', 
                    phraseto_tsquery('English','European Commercial Bank')::tsquery);
```

which produces:

| ts_semantic_headline |
| --- |
| This Commercial Bank does not have any Equity in Europe but <b>European Commercial Bank</b> does |

The `ts_semantic_headline` solution  uses `ts_headline` under the hood to produce content fragments. It then uses text parsing and customized TSVectors, along with the included `ts_fast_headline` function to perform multi-word highlighting with minimal (5-10%) performance cost on top of `ts_headline`.

If performance is of any concern, the `ts_fast_headline` function can also use 2 pre-processed columns (TSPVector + TEXT[]), and deliver highlighted content 5X-10X faster than `ts_headline`.