# Postgres: why did this trigram index slow down regexp queries?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-11, query-performance

I have a TEXT `keyvalues` column in Postgres:

```
select * from test5 limit 5;

 id |                      keyvalues
----+------------------------------------------------------
  1 | ^ first 1 | second 3
  2 | ^ first 1 | second 2 ^ first 2 | second 3
  3 | ^ first 1 | second 2 | second 3
  4 | ^ first 2 | second 3 ^ first 1 | second 2 | second 2
  5 | ^ first 2 | second 3 ^ first 1 | second 3
```

My queries must exclude the `^` character from the middle of the match, so I'm using regular expressions:

```
explain analyze select count(*) from test5 where keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0';

                                                              QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=78383.31..78383.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7332.030..7332.030 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=78383.10..78383.30 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=7332.021..7337.138 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=77383.10..77383.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7328.155..7328.156 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test5  (cost=0.00..77382.50 rows=238 width=0) (actual time=7328.146..7328.146 rows=0 loops=3)
                     Filter: (keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1666668
 Planning Time: 0.068 ms
 Execution Time: 7337.184 ms
```

The query works (zero rows match), but is way too slow at > 7 seconds.

I thought indexing with trigrams would help, but no luck:

```
create extension if not exists pg_trgm;
create index on test5 using gin (keyvalues gin_trgm_ops);

explain analyze select count(*) from test5 where keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0';
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1484.02..1484.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23734.646..23734.646 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test5  (cost=1480.00..1484.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=23734.641..23734.641 rows=0 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0'::text)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5000005
         Heap Blocks: exact=47620
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test5_keyvalues_idx  (cost=0.00..1480.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1756.158..1756.158 rows=5000005 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.412 ms
 Execution Time: 23734.722 ms
```

The query with the trigram index is **3x slower**! It still returns the correct result (zero rows). I expected the trigram index to figure out immediately there's no `second 0` string anywhere, and be super fast.

*(Motivation: I want to avoid normalizing the `keyvalues` into [another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485455/postgres-gin-trgm-ops-index-not-being-used), so I'm looking to encode the matching logic in a single `TEXT` field using text indexing and regexps instead. The logic works, but is too slow, [as is JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483600/composite-jsonb-array-query-in-postgres).)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected the trigram index to figure out immediately there's no `second 0` string anywhere

'second' and '0' are separate words, so it cannot detect their joint absence as such.  It seems like it could detect the absence of '  0', but this comment from "contrib/pg_trgm/trgm_regexp.c" seems pertinent:

```
 * Note: Using again the example "foo bar", we will not consider the
 * trigram "  b", though this trigram would be found by the trigram
 * extraction code.  Since we will find " ba", it doesn't seem worth
 * trying to hack the algorithm to generate the additional trigram.
```

Since 0 is the last character in the pattern string, there will be no trigram of the form " 0a", either, so it just misses that opportunity.

Even if it were not for this limitation, your approach seems extremely fragile.

Comment: Aha. I don't need any tokenization, the strings should match verbatim. I confirm removing whitespace fixes the issue. So that's what I'll do.

Comment: It's odd that `select * from test5 where keyvalues ~ '0'` still uses the index (after `set enable seqscan = off`)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter not that odd.  You've twisted its arm into it.  It is reading the entire index, stuffing every tid it finds into the bitmap.  The index does "apply" the condition, but that condition is incapable of ruling out any tids so the application of it is trivial.  Since you won't let it use a seqscan, this is what it does instead.

Comment: Yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff provided the explanation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240130/3684) you were looking for.

**Phrase search** as provided by the [text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) infrastructure might be your solution.

```
CREATE INDEX test5_keyvalues_ts_idx ON test5 USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', keyvalues));
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test5
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', keyvalues) @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple','first 1 second 3');
AND    keyvalues ~* '\^ first 1[^\^]+second 0';
```

Use the 'simple' text search configuration as you don't want language specific stemming.

The `^` character is significant in your case, but considered to be noise by the 'default' text search parser (the only one implemented, actually) - so not indexed. So narrow it down with the text search index, and filter with the regexp.

It's possible to add a custom parser, but I never tried that. And you want to negate its existence in the search pattern anyway, so I guess the above is your best shot.

Related:

- [How to search hyphenated words in PostgreSQL full text search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204588/how-to-search-hyphenated-words-in-postgresql-full-text-search/204601#204601)