# What is more efficient: text (765) or varchar (765) to store a freeform searchable description?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, full-text-search, varchar

**EDIT** : To paraphrase quesiton - at what point do I switch from varchar to text and back?

A little background on the question. Let's say we have sales_orders table and we want to be able to keep a note field on the order with customer's or sales reps comments. It needs to be searchable `LIKE "%goldfinger's gun%"` We know we are not going to have "War & Peace" stored in the field, but at same time it should be big enough to handle a sentence or two.

So which option is:

- faster for reads?
- better at storing data?
- better for full text searching?
- indexing?

Assume MySQL(InnoDB) or PostgreSQL use case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary:  VARCHAR and TEXT are identical for reading, storing, FULLTEXT, and virtually everything else.  Some INDEX/SELECT differences are noted below.

MariaDB and MySQL are (I'm pretty sure) the same as each other in this area.

Some reason for 765?  What CHARACTER SET are you using?  (Ascii versus utf8 -- there could be differences.)

For "small" VARCHARs (up to 512?), there is a minor advantage over TEXT:  When a query need to create a tmp table, small VARCHARs let it be done with MEMORY.  TEXT forces MyISAM for the tmp table.  This is likely to impact the speed of *some* queries (MEMORY is faster).

TEXT cannot have an ordinary INDEX; small VARCHARs can.  (I am not sure about 765; try CREATE TABLE; it will spit at you if that is too big.)

You can use a "prefix" index, such as `INDEX (foo(55))`, but it would be useless for your `LIKE`s, and often useless for any other purpose.

UUIDs should be packed into BINARY(16), similar to what was mentioned for Postgres.  16 is smaller, hence more efficient.

LIKE '%foo%' works the same for VARCHAR and TEXT.  Same speed, same syntax, etc.  The leading wildcard makes the use of an INDEX impossible, thereby disallowing any index optimization.

FULLTEXT indexes work on VARCHAR and TEXT, in MyISAM and (as of ~5.6.4) in InnoDB.  But FULLTEXT is *word* oriented and has a number of caveats.  Furthermore the caveats are different between MyISAM and InnoDB.

Comment: 765 - just wanted a number in a grey zone, not quite big enough for text, not quote small enough that it is obviously varchar.  - your comment about 512 addresses that perfectly. To clarify - I'm using utf-8 and InnoDB (technically XtraDB)

Comment: utf8 cutoff is `VARCHAR(255)` because it assumes up to 3 bytes per character.  (utf8mb4:  `VARCHAR(191)`)

Answer (score 5):

As far as **Postgres** is concerned, there is no difference in performance. And there is no length modifier for `text` to begin with, just (optionally) for `varchar`.

Unless you need to enforce a certain length, just use `text` or `varchar`.

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

To support pattern matching with `LIKE`, I suggest a trigram index. Details:

- [How to create an index to speed up an aggregate LIKE query on an expression?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/how-to-create-an-index-to-speed-up-an-aggregate-like-query-on-an-expression/21648#21648)

There is also [full-text-search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) with its own set of operators, building on dictionaries. Here's an overview of pattern-matching options in Postgres:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Comment: Thank you for both links. Do you know if there is difference in mysql or mariadb?

Comment: The trigram index is totally Postgres specific. As is the information concerning data types. There are other regulars here who are more competent with MySQL than me. I'll leave that part to them.

Comment: I think that PostgreSQL is far beyond these RDBMs perversions.