# Faster query with pattern-matching on multiple text fields

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search, performance, postgresql-performance

I have one Postgres table with more than 20M tuples:

```
first_name | last_name | email
-------------------------------------------
bat        | man       | batman@wayne.com
arya       | vidal     | foo@email.com
max        | joe       | bar@email.com
```

To filter the records I'm using:

```
SELECT *
  FROM people
WHERE (first_name || '' || last_name) ILIKE '%bat%man%' OR 
    first_name ILIKE '%bat%man%'  OR  
    last_name ILIKE '%bat%man%'   OR
    email ILIKE '%bat%man%'
    LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Even with indexes the search is taking almost **one minute** to return results.
There are indexes for `(first_name || '' || last_name)`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`.

What can I do to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: are you aware of [varchar_pattern_ops](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-opclass.html)?

Comment: I presume you are using ordinary B-tree indexes? These won't work for `ilike '%something'` (with leading wildcard). You'll need to add other indexes.

Comment: @Colin'tHart yes, it's a btree index. What kind of index should i add?

Comment: How does an `EXECUTE ANALYZE` output look like?

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using? Please edit this (and the fact that you are using B-tree indexes) into your question so we can delete these comments.

Comment: What's the purpose of concatenating `first_name` and `last_name` with a zero-length string between them?

Comment: ...and (as always) your actual table definition that shows actual data types and constraints: `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d people` in psql.

Comment: @SahapAsci: The `*_pattern_ops` operator classes are useful with left-anchored patterns, but impotent for the demonstrated use case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your kind of pattern matching you best use a trigram index. **Read this first:**

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

I assume there's a typo in your expression `(first_name || '' || last_name)`, which makes no sense with an empty string, and you really want `(first_name || ' ' || last_name)` - with a space character.

Assuming that either column can be NULL, you would need NULL-safe concatenation, the simple solution is `concat_ws()`:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860)

But that function is not `IMMUTABLE` (explanation in the linked answer), so you cannot use it directly in an index expression. You could use an `IMMUTABLE` function wrapper:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_immutable_concat_ws(s text, t1 text, t2 text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT concat_ws(s, t1, t2)';
```

The wrapper can be `IMMUTABLE` because it only takes `text` parameters. (But don't be tempted to coerce data types in the call for which text representation is not immutable!)

Either way, this is more verbose but has less internal overhead and is considerably faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_immutable_concat_ws(s text, t1 text, t2 text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE
         WHEN t1 IS NULL THEN t2
         WHEN t2 IS NULL THEN t1
         ELSE t1 || s || t2
       END
$func$;
```

Or, with hard-coded space character:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concat_space(t1 text, t2 text)
  RETURNS text AS
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
$func$
SELECT CASE
         WHEN t1 IS NULL THEN t2
         WHEN t2 IS NULL THEN t1
         ELSE t1 || ' ' || t2
       END
$func$;
```

Make it [`PARALLEL SAFE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-safety.html) (in Postgres 9.6 or later) to not stand in the way of parallelism. (And because it qualifies!)

Basing the index on the last function, I suggest:

```
CREATE INDEX people_gin_trgm_idx ON people
USING gin (f_concat_space(first_name, last_name) gin_trgm_ops, email gin_trgm_ops);
```

I added `email` as second index column because you seem to be checking both at the same time.

Creating the index will take a while for 20M rows, best not during top load, or maybe use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ...`. A GIN index can be considerably bigger than a plain B-tree index and is more expensive to maintain. Be sure to run the latest version of Postgres, there have been major improvements for GIN indexes in recent versions.

Then your slightly adapted and simplified query should be ***fast and correct***:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people
WHERE  f_concat_space(first_name, last_name) ILIKE '%bat%man%'
    OR email ILIKE '%bat%man%'
LIMIT  25;
```

You only need the *one* index for this query.

Related:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- [How to create an index to speed up an aggregate LIKE query on an expression?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/how-to-create-an-index-to-speed-up-an-aggregate-like-query-on-an-expression/21648#21648)
- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

Comment: Heh. Fast(ish) and correct. Infix searches are always going to be a bit slow. As for `concat_ws`, do you know why it's not `immutable`? I'd suggest checking that before just wrapping it, otherwise you might land up with index contents that don't match the current expression results for the same input, which behaves like index corruption.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I researched `concat_ws()` not being `IMMUTABLE` and added an explanation to [the answer referenced above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860). The explanation is rather simple and my wrapper is safe because it only takes `text` parameters.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I only raised it because I really don't want to encourage people to just bypass !immutable flags with wrappers.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You are totally right about that. I have seen crimes happening in that dark alley before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860. I added a note above for why the wrapper is safe.

Comment: I was wondering, how much of a speedup would the original poster have with this method?

Comment: @xtrinch: For big tables, a fitting trigram index can mean the difference between "instantaneous" and "takes forever".