# Find partial match with textsearch query

Tags: postgresql, query, full-text-search, pattern-matching, like

I have the following query that I did hard looking on this site:

```
SELECT *
FROM   renns
WHERE
    (
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(numar_admin, '')) || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_strada, '')) || 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_prenume, ''))|| 
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(bloc, '')) ||
        to_tsvector('english', coalesce(apartament, '')) 
    ) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', '$q')
```

It works if I write in the variable `$q` all the text that appears in one of the columns present in the query. For example: `cherry`

I would like to write only: `cher` and return all rows fields in which it finds this string: "cher".

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

Postgres text search supports ***prefix matching***:

```
SELECT *
FROM   renns
WHERE (
   to_tsvector('english', coalesce(numar_admin, '')) || 
   to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_strada, '')) || 
   to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_prenume, ''))|| 
   to_tsvector('english', coalesce(bloc, '')) ||
   to_tsvector('english', coalesce(apartament, '')) 
) @@ to_tsquery('simple', $q || ':*');
```

(`$q` being a single word.)
This can use an index on your expression:

```
(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(numar_admin , '')) || 
 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_strada , '')) || 
 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_prenume, '')) || 
 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(bloc        , '')) ||
 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(apartament  , '')))
```

Using the `'simple'` dictionary disables stemming. If you want stemming, use the 'english' dictionary like you had before.

> "caisului 498:*"  the "CAISULUI" string is from one column and the number from another column of the `renns` table

To pass **multiple** lexemes, apply `'english'` stemming and do prefix matching for all of them:

```
@@ (to_tsquery('english', column_a || ':*') &&
    to_tsquery('english', column_b || ':*') -- more?   
   )
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)

***Prefix*** matching matches at the start of lexemes. For any partial match, you can use `LIKE` or regular expression matches (`~`) in combination with a trigram index. Different approach! Requires a different query and a different index! See:

- [How to create an index to speed up an aggregate LIKE query on an expression?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/how-to-create-an-index-to-speed-up-an-aggregate-like-query-on-an-expression/21648#21648)
- [Faster query with pattern-matching on multiple text fields](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117403/faster-query-with-pattern-matching-on-multiple-text-fields/117425#117425)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

There are smart ways to integrate both. [The manual has an example.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.9)

Comment: I have an error: "SELECT * FROM renns WHERE ( to_tsvector('english', coalesce(numar_admin, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_strada, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(nume_prenume, ''))|| to_tsvector('english', coalesce(bloc, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(apartament, '')) ) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'caisului 498' || ':*')" $q = "caisului 498" and error: syntax error in tsquery: "caisului 498:*" :(  the "CAISULUI" string is from one column and the number from another column of the renns table

Comment: `to_tsquery('simple', 'cher' || ':*')` only works for a *single* lexeme. You tried to pass multiple. Which of the words is meant for prefix maching? All of them?

Comment: I should be able to search for several words in $ q that correspond to several columns in the table from 1 to all if possible.

I apologize for the poor explanation but I'm not very good at pgsql :(

Comment: @CoderCoder42: I added some more for your case.

Comment: @@ (to_tsquery('english', numar_admin || ':*') && to_tsquery('english', nume_strada || ':*');";

I tried this, but I got an error: syntax error at or near ";" LINE 12: ... dmin || ': *') && to_tsquery ('english', nume_strada || ': *'); ^ and where do I put $ q?

Comment: @CoderCoder42: Missing closing parenthesis at the end. And this *replaces* `$ q`.

Comment: This is @@ (to_tsquery('english', 'caisului 498' || ':*') && to_tsquery('english', 'caisului 498' || ':*') );" I try this way "caisului 498" when I write caisului  in letters one by one it gives me good results but when I try to write 498 it doesn't return anything :( that 498 is in a different column than apricot