# Increasing work_mem and shared_buffers on Postgres 9.2 significantly slows down queries

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a PostgreSQL 9.2 instance running on RHEL 6.3, 8-core machine with 16GB of RAM. The server is dedicated to this database. Given that the default postgresql.conf is quite conservative regarding memory settings, I thought it might be a good idea to allow Postgres to use more memory. To my surprise, following advice on [wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) significantly slowed down practically every query I run but it's obviously more noticeable on the more complex queries.

I also tried running pgtune which gave the following recommendation with more parameters tuned, but that didn't change anything. It suggests shared_buffers of 1/4 of RAM size which seems to in line with advice elsewhere (and on PG wiki in particular).

```
default_statistics_target = 50
maintenance_work_mem = 960MB
constraint_exclusion = on
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 11GB
work_mem = 96MB
wal_buffers = 8MB
checkpoint_segments = 16
shared_buffers = 3840MB
max_connections = 80
```

I tried reindexing the whole database after changing the settings (using `reindex database`), but that didn't help either. I played around with shared_buffers and work_mem. Gradually changing them from the very conservative default values (128k / 1MB) gradually decreased performance.

I ran `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` on a few queries and the culprit seems to be that Hash Join is significantly slower. It's not clear to me why.

To give some specific example, I have the following query. It runs in ~2100ms on the default configuration and ~3300ms on the configuration with increased buffer sizes:

```
select count(*) from contest c
left outer join contestparticipant cp on c.id=cp.contestId
left outer join teammember tm on tm.contestparticipantid=cp.id
left outer join staffmember sm on cp.id=sm.contestparticipantid
left outer join person p on p.id=cp.personid
left outer join personinfo pi on pi.id=cp.personinfoid
where pi.lastname like '%b%' or pi.firstname like '%a%';
```

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` for the query above:

- Default buffers: http://explain.depesz.com/s/xaHJ
- Bigger buffers: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Plk

The question is **why am I observing decreased performance when I increase buffer sizes?** The machine is definitely not running out of memory. Allocation if shared memory in OS is (`shmmax` and `shmall`) is set to very large values, that should not be a problem. I'm not getting any errors in the Postgres log either. I'm running autovacuum in the default configuration but I don't expect that has anything to do with it. All queries were run on the same machine few seconds apart, just with changed configuration (and restarted PG).

Edit:
I just found one particularly interesting fact: when I perform the same test on my mid-2010 iMac (OSX 10.7.5) also with Postgres 9.2.1 and 16GB RAM, I don't experience the slow down.
Specifically:

```
set work_mem='1MB';
select ...; // running time is ~1800 ms
set work_mem='96MB';
select ...' // running time is ~1500 ms
```

When I do exactly the same query (the one above) with exactly the same data on the server I get 2100 ms with work_mem=1MB and 3200 ms with 96 MB.

The Mac has SSD so it's understandably faster, but it exhibits a behavior I would expect.

See also the [follow-up discussion on pgsql-performance](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2012-11/msg00004.php).

Comment: It looks like that in the slower case every step is consistenly slower.  Did other settings remain the same?

Comment: It's probably worth your while to ask this on a more specialised forum rather than the generic one that this is. In this case I suggest the pgsql-general mailing list http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/

Comment: Oh, and report back and please answer your own question if you find the answer! (This is allowed, encouraged even).

Comment: @dezso Yes, all other settings remained the same.

Comment: @Colin'tHart thanks for suggestions, I'll try posting there. Or perhaps pgsql-performance?

Comment: Either or both :-)

Comment: I do wonder how similar Postgres is to Oracle in this regard: I remember a course by Jonathan Lewis (Oracle guru) in which he demonstrated that allocating more memory to sorts sometimes made them slower. I forget the specifics but it was something to do with that Oracle does partial sorts and then writes them out to temporary storage and then combines them later. Somehow more memory made this process slower.

Comment: I found this http://www.depesz.com/2011/07/03/understanding-postgresql-conf-work_mem/ where the author also found that allocating more memory to sorts made them slightly slower.

Comment: @Colin'tHart thanks! That's the closest thing to my problem I've seen so far :)

Comment: @PetrPraus Did you land up posting on the PostgreSQL mailing lists? I don't see the question on pgsql-general or pgsql-performance. I was looking for it so I could add a link back to it here.

Comment: @CraigRinger I did post it to pgsql-performance but I got "Stalled post to pgsql-performance". It's apparently waiting for moderator approval and moderator has not approved it yet :(

Comment: The question is now posted on pgsql-performance: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2012-11/msg00004.php

Comment: this one: `default_statistics_target = 50` seems strange to me. I would probably *increase* that dramatically - especially as the default is 100. Higher values might give the planner better information.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're completely right, I noticed that pgtune in this case gave a weird number and later set that to 100. I'll try increasing that, but change between 50/100 didn't do anything to my problem.

Comment: It sounds like your table statistics are incorrect (have you adjusted the number of rows that are considered for statistics?) or one or more of `*_cost` parameters have bad mismatch with your actual hardware performance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that work_mem is *per operation* and so it can get excessive pretty quickly.  In general if you are not having trouble with sorts being slow I would leave work_mem alone until you need it.

Looking at your query plans, one thing that strikes me is that the buffer hits are very different looking at the two plans, and that even the sequential scans are slower.  I suspect that the issue has to do with read-ahead caching and having less space for that.  What this means is you are biasing memory for re-use of indexes and against reading tables on disk.

---

My understanding is that PostgreSQL will look to the cache for a page before reading it from disk because it doesn't know really whether the OS cache will contain that page.  Because the pages are then staying in the cache and because that cache is slower than the OS cache, this changes the sorts of queries which are fast vs the sorts that are slow.  In fact reading the plans, aside from work_mem issues, it looks like all of your query info comes from the cache but it is a question of which cache.

**work_mem**: how much memory we can allocate for a sort or related join operation.  This is per operation, not per statement or per back-end, so a single complex query can use many times this amount of memory.  It isn't clear you are hitting this limit but it is worth noting and being aware of.  if you increase this too far, you lose memory that might be available for the read cache and the shared buffers.

**shared_buffers**: how much memory to allocate to the actual PostgreSQL page queue.  Now, ideally the interesting set of your database will stay in memory cached here and in the read buffers.  However, what this does is ensure that the most frequently used information across all backends gets cached and not flushed to disk.  On Linux this cache is significantly slower than the OS disk cache, but it offers guarantees that the OS disk cache dos not and is transparent to PostgreSQL.  This is pretty clearly where your problem is.

So what happens is that when we have a request, we check the shared buffers first since PostgreSQL has deep knowledge of this cache, and look for the pages.  If they are not there we ask the OS to open them from the file, and if the OS has cached the result it returns the cached copy (this is faster than the shared buffers, but Pg can't tell whether it is cached or on disk, and disk is *much* slower so PostgreSQL typically will not take that chance).  Keep in mind this affects random vs sequential page access as well.  So you may get better performance with lower shared_buffers settings.

My gut sense is that you probably get better, or at least more consistent, performance in high concurrency environments with larger shared_buffer settings.  Also keep in mind that PostgreSQL grabs this memory and holds it so if you have other things running on the system, the read buffers will hold files read by other processes.  It's a very large and complex topic.   Larger shared buffer settings provide better *guarantees* of performance but may deliver less performance in some cases.

Answer (score 14):

Apart from the seemingly paradoxical effect that increasing `work_mem` decreases performance ([@Chris](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33616/3684) might have an explanation), you can improve your function in at least two ways.

#### 1.

Rewrite two fake `LEFT JOIN`'s with `JOIN`. That might confuse the query planner and lead to inferior plans.

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   contest            c
JOIN   contestparticipant cp ON cp.contestId = c.id
JOIN   personinfo         pi ON pi.id = cp.personinfoid
LEFT   JOIN teammember    tm ON tm.contestparticipantid = cp.id
LEFT   JOIN staffmember   sm ON sm.contestparticipantid = cp.id
LEFT   JOIN person        p  ON p.id = cp.personid
WHERE (pi.firstname LIKE '%a%'
OR     pi.lastname  LIKE '%b%')
```

#### 2.

Assuming that your actual search patterns are more selective, use trigram indexes on `pi.firstname` and `pi.lastname` to support non-anchored `LIKE` searches. (Shorter patterns like `'%a%'` are supported as well but an index is not likely to help for non-selective predicates.):

```
CREATE INDEX personinfo_firstname_gin_idx ON personinfo USING gin (firstname gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX personinfo_lastname_gin_idx  ON personinfo USING gin (lastname gin_trgm_ops);
```

Or one multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX personinfo_name_gin_idx ON personinfo USING gin (firstname gin_trgm_ops, lastname gin_trgm_ops);
```

Should make your query quite a bit faster. You need to install the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) for this. Details under these related questions:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

---

Also, have you tried setting `work_mem` locally - [for the current transaction only](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)?

```
SET LOCAL work_mem = '96MB';
```

This keeps concurrent transactions from also eating more RAM, possibly starving each other.

Comment: I want to second Erwin's local work_mem suggestion.  Because work_mem changes the sorts of queries that are faster, you may need to change it for some queries.  I.e. low work_mem levels are best for queries which sort/join small numbers of records in complex ways (i.e. lots of joins) while high work_mem levels are best for queries which have a few sorts but which sort or join a large number of rows at once.

Comment: I improved the query in the meantime (the question is from October last year) but thanks :) This question is more about the unexpected effect than the particular query. The query serves mainly to demonstrate the effect. Thanks for the tip on the index, I'll try that!