# Full Text Search With PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-9.2

i have a table with this rows:

```
Stickers
------------------------------------------------------
ID | Title                 |Keywords (ts_vector)
------------------------------------------------------
01 | Sticker Case 580H     |'580h':3 'cas':2 'stick':1
02 | Sticker Case 580L     |'580l':3 'cas':2 'stick':1
03 | Sticker Case 580      |'580':3 'cas':2 'stick':1
04 | Sticker Case Plus 3000|'3000':4 'cas':2 'plus':3 'stick':1
```

Well, when i do search using this script, just row 03 return, how i do return the row 01 and 02?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
stickers
WHERE
keywords @@@ to_tsquery('case & 580');
```

Comment: You can use : to_tsquery('case & 580*') Note the asterisk after 580.

Comment: We implement the Apache Solr for this situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really a use case for full text search because full text relies on stemming the text and parsing the chunks into tokens. As you can see from `keywords`, '580h' is parsed as its own word because there's no language in which '580' is a "stem" of '580h'. You'd probably be better off with regular expression matching.

Here's a query that I worked up for you:

```
SELECT id, title 
  FROM stickers WHERE
    (title ~* '580')
      AND
    (title ~* 'case')
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what [swasheck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/4490/swasheck) explained, you'll probably get better performance with [`LIKE` (`~~`) and `ILIKE` (`~~*`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) in combination with a **trigram GiST or GIN index**. You'll have to install the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) for that. See:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Trigram indexes can be used for *basic* regular expression matches (`~`) as well, but `LIKE` is generally faster.

Create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX stickers_title_gin_trgm_idx ON stickers
USING gin (title gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then this should be very fast:

```
SELECT *
FROM   stickers
WHERE  title ~~* '%case 580%';
```

Or (not clear from your question):

```
SELECT *
FROM   stickers
WHERE  title ~~* '%case%'
AND    title ~~  '%580%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
stickers
WHERE
keywords @@ to_tsquery('case & 580:*')
```

will work.

Postgres text search allows for prefix searching, which is represented by the :* in the query. It will match any token starting with 580

Comment: Some explanation could probably repel downvotes.