# Postgres, levenshtein distance and nested queries

Tags: postgresql, subquery, explain

I have a DB Table with 3,000,000 rows or more like that:

```
|ID|T4|T16|T64|TL
```

where ID =INTEGER (PK)
and T4,T16,T64,TL are text fields. Each one is larger in length than the previous, i.e., LENGTH(T4)

I want to compare one row of this table with a SELF JOIN with all other rows based on the levenshtein distance (fuzzystrmatch extension) between TL of the compared rows and get the best-k results that correspond to smaller levenstein distance.

```
SELECT n1.*,n2.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE ID =110) n1,
dbtable n2
ORDER BY levenshtein_less_equal(n1.TL,n2.TL,LENGTH(n1.TEXT)/4) LIMIT 100;
```

Of course this would be extremely slow because it will have to do 3,000,000 levenshtein calculations.

In order to accelerate queries, I have created the artificial "hashes" (fields T4,T16,T64). So, I want to check initially levenshtein distance between fields T4. If this distance between T4 is within some limit then I check levenshtein distance between T16 and so-on. This way in each step i would need to calculate fewer levenshtein distances that by the naive approach.

The nested query is like that:

```
SELECT n5.*,levenshtein_less_equal(n5.n1_tl,n5.n2_tl,LENGTH(n5.n1_tl)/4)
FROM
(SELECT n4.*
FROM
(SELECT n3.*
FROM
(SELECT 
n1.id AS n1_id,
n1.t4 AS n1_t4,
n1.t16 AS n1_t16,
n1.t64 AS n1_t64,
n1.tl AS n1_tl,

n2.id AS n2_id,
n2.t4 AS n2_t4,
n2.t16 AS n2_t16,
n2.t64 AS n2_t64,
n2.tl AS n2_tl
FROM (SELECT id,t4,t16,t64,tl FROM dbTable WHERE id=110) AS n1,dbTable AS n2
WHERE
n1.id<>n2.id
AND levenshtein_less_equal(n1.t4,n2.t4,LENGTH(n1.t4)) <= LENGTH(n1.t4)/2
) n3

WHERE levenshtein_less_equal(n3.n1_t16,n3.n2_t16,LENGTH(n3.n1_t16)/2) < LENGTH(n3.n1_t16)/2 
) AS n4

WHERE levenshtein_less_equal(n4.n1_t64,n4.n2_t64,LENGTH(n4.n1_t64)/2) < LENGTH(n4.n1_t64)/2)
AS n5
ORDER BY levenshtein_less_equal(n5.n1_tl,n5.n2_tl,LENGTH(n5.n1_tl)/4)
LIMIT 100;
```

The query is much faster than the original naive since it only needs to access 112851 rows for TL but:

The EXPLAIN PLAN:

```
Limit  (cost=872281.90..872282.15 rows=100 width=1168)
  ->  Sort  (cost=872281.90..872564.03 rows=112851 width=1168)
        Sort Key: (levenshtein_less_equal(dbTable.tl, n2.tl, (length(dbTable.tl) / 4)))
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..867968.81 rows=112851 width=1168)
              Join Filter: ((dbTable.id <> n2.id) AND (levenshtein_less_equal(dbTable.t4, n2.t4, length(dbTable.t4)) <= (length(dbTable.t4) / 2)) AND (levenshtein_less_equal(dbTable.t16, n2.t16, (length(dbTable.t16) / 2)) < (length(dbTable.t16) / 2)) AND (levenshtein_less_equal(dbTable.t64, n2.t64, (length(dbTable.t64) / 2)) < (length(dbTable.t64) / 2)))
              ->  Index Scan using dbTable_pkey on dbTable  (cost=0.00..8.60 rows=1 width=584)
                    Index Cond: (id = 110)
              ->  Seq Scan on dbTable n2  (cost=0.00..699529.82 rows=3046982 width=584)
```

As you see the problem is that the query optimizer joins / collapses the levenshtein distance calculations between T4, T16, T64, where without collapsing it would be probably faster, because fewer levenshtein distances would need to be made for T64. I used  SET from_collapse_limit=1; to avoid collapsing at the same session but nothing changed. Is there a way to enforce this hierarchical functionality in a Postgres query; Keep in mind that none of the T4...TL are indexed because I do not think there is an index to accelerate levenshtein distances. Any suggestions to further improve performance?

Comment: You just need to use WITH. Have a look, it's very simple and it will make your query easier to the eye http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html

Comment: How long is your shortest `TL`?

Comment: TL may range from 10-1600 chars. I had to built levenshtein from src to work with such long strings. On the other hand t4 is small (max 16). That is why it is faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use a trigram index provided by the additional module [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).  Combine that with the *length* of the string to get a valid pre-selection.

1. Drop the columns `T4`,`T16` and `T64` (faster in a single statement), and run `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER`.
2. Install `pg_trgm`. Details here:

   - [Full Text Search With PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33561/full-text-search-with-postgresql/33591#33591)
3. Create a GiST index on `tl` and `length(tl)`.

There are a details to be observed. Related answers on dba.SE involving `pg_trgm`:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=pg_trgm

Comment: Why use a gist index on length(tl);

Comment: It did not work for my case, it was much slower. Still, +1 for your effort.