# Postgres pg_trgm JOIN multiple columns with large tables (~50 million rows)

Tags: postgresql, index, join, full-text-search

I'm trying to perform a query on Postgres using the pg_trgm extension that attempts to fuzzy match across multiple columns in two tables. I've let the query run for an hour or more and it hasn't finished. I'm able to get results after a few minutes by setting a LIMIT of 10 or 100, but anything beyond that takes forever and doesn't finish. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM schema1.X a
JOIN schema2.Y b
  ON (
    b.name % a.track_title
    AND b.artist_display_name % a.artist
    AND b.collection_display_name % a.release_title
  )
```

I've indexed each of the individual columns here on both tables with GIN, and I've added a composite GIN index on both tables for the columns in the same order as the query (composite of `track_title`,`artist`,`release_title` on `schema1.X` and composite of `name`,`artist_display_name`,`collection_display_name` on `schema2.Y`).
**EDIT**: I should also probably mention that `schema1.X` contains about 50,000 rows and `schema2.Y` contains about 50 million rows. All three fields being compared in the JOIN are of type TEXT. The EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of this query is the following (run with a LIMIT of 10 rows so I could get it to finish in a reasonable amount of time):

```
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43.18..2460373.14 rows=2696 width=71) (actual time=4922.361..8640.818 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on schema1.X a  (cost=0.00..1261.91 rows=52091 width=48) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on schema2.Y b  (cost=43.18..47.20 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=4300.048..4320.303 rows=5 loops=2)
              Recheck Cond: (((name)::text % (a.track_title)::text) AND ((artist_display_name)::text % (a.artist)::text) AND ((collection_display_name)::text % (a.release_title)::text))
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1390
              Heap Blocks: exact=2715
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_gin_name_artist_collection  (cost=0.00..43.18 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=4297.353..4297.353 rows=1414 loops=2)
                    Index Cond: (((name)::text % (a.track_title)::text) AND ((artist_display_name)::text % (a.artist)::text) AND ((collection_display_name)::text % (a.release_title)::text))
Planning time: 0.316 ms
Execution time: 8641.760 ms
```

It appears to be using my composite index from one table (the `Bitmap Index Scan on idx_gin_name_artist_collection`) but not from the other. Here are some of the links I reviewed:

- [Mixed search in multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71593/mixed-search-in-multiple-columns)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589444/multi-column-index-for-string-match-string-similarity-with-pg-trgm

In case it's important, I used this syntax to create the GIN indexes (filling in my table and column names of course):

```
CREATE INDEX  "table_idx" ON "schema"."table"
  USING gin(field_name COLLATE "default" "public"."gin_trgm_ops")
  WITH (FASTUPDATE = YES);
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Does pg_trgm work within a JOIN clause? Most of the examples I can find are using the % operator in the WHERE clause. Also, should I expect this to run in a reasonable amount of time (minutes) on tables this large, even with indexes?

**EDIT**

Here is the EXPLAIN plan when I remove the LIMIT from the query:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=43.18..2460373.14 rows=2696 width=71)
  ->  Seq Scan on schema1.X a  (cost=0.00..1261.91 rows=52091 width=48)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on schema2.Y b  (cost=43.18..47.20 rows=1 width=71)
        Recheck Cond: (((name)::text % (a.track_title)::text) AND ((artist_display_name)::text % (a.artist)::text) AND ((collection_display_name)::text % (a.release_title)::text))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_gin_song_name_artist_collection  (cost=0.00..43.18 rows=1 width=0)
              Index Cond: (((name)::text % (a.track_title)::text) AND ((artist_display_name)::text % (a.artist)::text) AND ((collection_display_name)::text % (a.release_title)::text))
```

**Follow-up questions:**

- Could I create a separate column of all three field concat'd or hashed for each table, and then index that column? Or is that what the composite GIN index is already doing?
- Does casting play a role in slowing  the query down? I notice in the EXPLAIN plan that the index is casting each field as `::text` even though they are all `varchar(256)`.
- Alternative solutions: Would a columnar data store like Redshift be any more efficient at this? Does Redshift even have the ability to install extensions like `pg_trgm`? Are other fuzzy search tools better at this kind of multi-column searching (e.g. ElasticSearch)?

Comment: try `set enable_seqscan = off` and rerunning the query. See if it speeds up at all. Also I find your

Comment: % works with a JOIN. In any case, I think your query will need to sequentially scan the smaller table (Y), and have a nested loop to the other one. And even if trigram searches are quite fast... they're not as fast as an equality comparison. I'm making a rough simulation... and my computer is already spending 15 min. It works. It's slow.

Comment: Some further preliminary trials suggests that there *might* be something wrong with using it with a GIN index. GIST seem to work better (and take a long time to create).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I posted that EXPLAIN plan without the limit. @joanolo I was going off of  [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) which suggests that GIN are better for static data and lookups, which fits my scenario. More timing info: LIMIT 100 takes ~3 min. I'd expect the query to return hundreds of thousands of rows, so I'd expect it to run much faster.

Answer (score 2):

This type of join cannot effectively use an index-to-index join.  One of the tables is going to need to be seq scanned.  You might want to try forcing it to reverse which table gets seq scanned, for example by dropping the gin index on the larger table so it can't be used, or appending the empty string to each column of the large table, such as `on ((b.name||'') % a.track_title and ...`.  Doing this will probably only work if you are limited by IO, not CPU.

> Also, should I expect this to run in a reasonable amount of time (minutes) on tables this large, even with indexes?

No, I don't think so.  There might be some things you can do to improve performance, but you are fundamentally asking the database to do a massive amount of work and it will take a long time to do it.

Make sure you are using the latest version of pg_trgm, which is 1.3.  This can help a lot for LIKE queries, but don't expect miracles for % queries.

Increase the value of pg_trgm.similarity_threshold as much as you can while still obtaining the number of results you want.  The default value of 0.3 is really very low.

It is not clear that the multi-column index is actually going to be helpful.  Try dropping it and see how it does with the individual column indexes.

Also, just be patient.  This looks to me like a data-cleaning exercise, not something you need to run interactively.  Maintain a materialized view, or a join table updated by triggers, to record the matches if need to be able to retrieve them interactively.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, I hadn't thought of adjusting the similarity threshold. I will give these suggestions a shot and report back.

Comment: Also @jjanes, was looking at your suggestion: "...where the larger table is seq scanned and the smaller one is indexed scanned..." - If I'm ready the EXPLAIN plan correctly, I think the opposite is happening: I'm sequentially scanning `schema1.X` which is the smaller table with 50K rows, and index scanning `schema2.Y` which is the table with 50 million rows (`idx_gin_song_name_artist_collection` is the 3-field composite on the large table). Am I reading that right?

Comment: I would expect the *smaller* table to be sequentially scanned.

Comment: @tom-g  Your question's text has those sizes reversed, saying X is 50m and Y is 50k.  Or am I reading it wrong?  But the EXPLAIN does seem to support the reversed sizes.

Comment: @joanolo It will be much harder to keep the entire table+index of the larger table cached in RAM.  So it would be better to seq scan it, so the smaller table+index can be cached instead.  Whether the planner is aware of this fact and will act on it, I don't know.

Comment: Experimental result: it is the small table which is sequentially scanned. Although this might depend on my database settings [which are more or less the default ones].

Comment: @jjanes and @joanolo you are correct - I got the row counts reversed in my question text (confused myself by obscuring the schema/table names). I've edited to reflect this, so `schema1.X` is the smaller 50K row table and `schema2.Y` is 50 million row table.

Comment: Following up on this. Wasn't able to get much improvement by tweaking the pg_trgm threshold or removing composite indexes. I let the query run for ~24 hrs and it was able to JOIN on about 7000 records from the smaller table before I stopped it (I'd expect almost all 50K from the smaller table to have a fuzzy match on the bigger table). I added some follow-up questions to my original post after experimenting some more. If there's not much else I can do I will go ahead and mark @jjanes's answer as accepted. Thanks.