# Postgres: Disable "similarity" column output on "SELECT SIMILARITY"?

Tags: postgresql, select, nearest-neighbor

I've tried disabling `similarity` column output on `SELECT SIMILARITY` but still cannot.

Below query will generate a column `similarity`:

```
SELECT SIMILARITY(title, 'Nation'), title
FROM gallery
WHERE title % 'Nation'
ORDER BY similarity DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Below query does not output `similarity` column but I am unable to sort:

```
SELECT title FROM gallery WHERE title % 'Nation';
```

Comment: Like this:?  `SELECT title FROM gallery WHERE title % 'Nation' ORDER BY SIMILARITY(title, 'Nation') DESC LIMIT 5;`

Comment: That works but it not following `set_limit`. When set `set_limit` value is `0.3`, it will get from `0.2`. I'm not sure if this is caused by Postgres bug. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: There must be an additional misunderstanding here. You won't get results with a similarity of `0.2` after running `SELECT set_limit(0.3)` *in the same session*. ypercube's query should work. You are aware that the setting only persists for the duration of the *current session*? Compare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034559/how-to-run-functions-every-time-postgresql-starts/27036570#27036570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can always wrap a query as subquery if you don't want to output all rows:

```
SELECT title FROM (SELECT ...) sub;
```

But you can also use expressions in `ORDER BY`, not just input or output columns. So there is no need for this (like [@ypercube already commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101824/postgres-disable-similarity-column-output-on-select-similarity#comment184218_101824)).

For the case at hand, it must be mentioned that you are using the additional module [**pg_trgm**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.htm). What you are trying to do can be simplified to:

```
SELECT title
FROM   gallery
WHERE  title % 'Nation'
ORDER  BY title <-> 'Nation'
LIMIT  5;
```

I replaced `SIMILARITY(title, 'Nation') DESC` with the simpler, equivalent `title <-> 'Nation'`, since the **`<->`** operator ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE)):

> Returns the "distance" between the arguments, that is one minus the `similarity()` value.

Either version works, but the latter is shorter and index support is bound to the operator, not the function. And you should have a GiST index on `title`.

Details:

- [PostgreSQL FTS and Trigram-similarity Query Optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56224/postgresql-fts-and-trigram-similarity-query-optimization/56232#56232)

Also relevant:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250001/939860)