# How to force PostgreSQL delete statement to use unique constraint index?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table defined with a unique constraint on 4 columns:

```sql
create table public.values (
  id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
  a smallint not null references .... (id),
  b smallint not null,
  c smallint not null,
  d int not null references .... (id),
  -- ... some other cols
  constraint unique_cols unique (a, b, c, d)
);

create index values_d on public.values using btree (dasc);
```

And this table has a lot of rows (it's +/- 400GB and grows by 8GB each day) - I think it's about 2.5 billion rows at this point. I want to delete rows identified via column `a`, but unless I specify either `b` or `c` in the where clause, the query plan indicates that a sequential scan on `public.values` will be done.

i.e. this query:

```sql
-- ... After running `analyze` on the tables that are used

explain delete from public.values where a = 2
```

shows the query plan (with 60 unique `a` values):

```
Delete on "values"  (cost=0.00..62375313.80 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Seq Scan on "values"  (cost=0.00..62375313.80 rows=48160325 width=6)
        Filter: (a = 2)
JIT:
  Functions: 3
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

This makes no sense to me - I don't understand why the unique constraint index isn't used (I would expect this query to delete 50 million rows).

If I update the query to specify `b`, then I can get the query plan to
indicate that an index scan will be done:

```sql
explain delete from public.values where a = 2 and b = 1
```

Shows this query plan:

```
Delete on "values"  (cost=0.58..4845719.33 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Index Scan using values_unique_cols on "values"  (cost=0.58..4845719.33 rows=1940861 width=6)
        Index Cond: ((a = 2) AND (b = 1))
JIT:
  Functions: 3
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Then if I change the delete query `b` clause "where" condition to be a `greater than` condition:

```sql
explain delete from public.values where a = 2 and b >= 1
```

... Back to the sequential scan.

**BUT** Changing the clause again:

```sql
explain delete from public.values where a = 2 and b  >= 7
```

And the plan is better (`b lower than 6` results in a seq scan - b is a value between 1 and 20):

```sql
Delete on "values"  (cost=0.58..65344628.48 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Index Scan using values_unique_cols on "values"  (cost=0.58..65344628.48 rows=36595426 width=6)
        Index Cond: ((a = 2) AND (b >= 7))
JIT:
  Functions: 3
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

How can I force PostgreSQL to use an index for a particular operation, or otherwise delete a large number of rows quickly?

I could run the query multiple times from the application, each time with a new `b` value, but I would prefer to make a single database call.

== EDIT

Subsequently to posting this question, I created an index on `a`, and re-analyzed the table. But the planner still indicates a seq. scan.

Comment: For deleting 2% of a table, I would expect the seq scan to actually be faster.  Are you sure it isn't?

Comment: Discussion of `random_page_cost` and indexes: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114868/234725

Comment: @jjanes I hadn't actually thought of that. I'll try it. My first attempt was actually to have a cascade delete on the a column. But that didn't work - I assumed that it was because the trigger was using a seq scan, which I thought was the problem. Would a cascade delete be slower than delete where id = 2?

Comment: Lowering the `random_page_cost` parameter results in the database choosing to use an index - and the query completes in a reasonable time. I have previously tried the seq. scan and it took much longer, but I can't remember if the table structure was the same (I think I had additional spatial indexes and columns). In any case, with the adjusted `random_page_cost` parameter the query is fast enough, and that is the answer I was looking for @dwhitemv. Thanks

Comment: I’d written a big essay on i/o costs as my first answer and deleted it since it wasn’t as big an effect in my environment, but that reinforces how situation-specific tuning is. Glad to hear it helped in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot *force* PostgreSQL to use an index for a command. You have to make the index appetizing enough for the planner to choose it.

Based on your description of your table activity, I suspect your column statistics are inaccurate and that is throwing off plan choice. You can also influence the planner by changing the I/O cost values to move the threshold between index and sequential scans, but there lies dragons.

As for a cascaded delete, it will depend on how the planner builds the subquery. I think it would translate into something like `DELETE FROM values WHERE a=2 AND d=2` which will break on whether the selectivity of `d` is better than `a` and thus if the `values_d` index is more useful than the unique index, if any index at all.

References:

- [PostgreSQL manual: CREATE STATISTICS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html)
- [PostgreSQL manual: Planner Cost Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS)