# Combine indexes to optimize "OR" queries

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

I know that since version 8.1 Postgres can use multiple indexes for queries with `or` *at query time*.

I wonder if it is possible to combine multiple columns into one index column *at index time*. That is if I have a query:

```
select *
from contacts
where firstname = 'Cassidy'
or lastname = 'Cassidy'
or nickname = 'Cassidy'
```

Can I create an index that unions all the values from `firstname`, `lastname` and `nickname` so that this search (possibly with an adapted query) becomes a single index lookup?

Comment: What happens if you add 3 separate indexes, one on `(firstname)`, another on `(lastname)` and another on `(nickname)`? Does the plan show that they are used?

Answer (score 2):

#### Query

Note this equivalent sorter syntax for your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   contacts
WHERE  'Cassidy' IN (firstname, lastname, nickname);
```

Resolves to the same expressions in the [*query tree*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parser-stage.html#id-1.10.3.6.4):

```
  (('Cassidy'::text = contacts.firstname)
OR ('Cassidy'::text = contacts.lastname)
OR ('Cassidy'::text = contacts.nickname))
```

The three columns can even have different data types. The single given string literal `'Cassidy'` is cast to different data types for this. *Exactly* like in your original query.

#### Index

You *could* use a *single* [bloom index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bloom.html) (after installing the additional module, once per database):

```
CREATE INDEX contacts_bloom_idx ON contacts USING bloom (firstname, lastname, nickname);
```

Especially if you have more candidate columns like this and query random combinations. Also if you are short on disk / cache memory or the index is rarely needed (so not in cache). Then *size* matters more and a bloom index is typically small.

But it's better for `AND`-ed conditions, less so for `OR`-ed conditions. [And the manual advises:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/bloom.html)

> This type of index is most useful when a table has many attributes and
>   queries test arbitrary combinations of them. **A traditional btree index
>   is faster than a bloom index**, but it can require many btree indexes to
>   support all possible queries where one needs only a single bloom
>   index. Note however that bloom indexes only support equality queries,
>   whereas btree indexes can also perform inequality and range searches.

And:

> Only operator classes for `int4` and `text` are included with the module.

For just three columns, three simple btree indexes should be faster and more versatile:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (firstname);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (lastname);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (nickname);
```

Postgres can rather efficiently combine multiple indexes in a bitmap index scan. Related:

- [What is a “bitmap index”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869155/what-is-a-bitmap-index/19869655#19869655)
- [PostgreSQL FTS and Trigram-similarity Query Optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56224/postgresql-fts-and-trigram-similarity-query-optimization/56232#56232)

---

A multicolumn index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (firstname, lastname, nickname);
```

is ***not very usefull*** for this. It happens to cover `firstname` as first column moderately well (not as well as a smaller index on just `(firstname)`). Additional columns are covered poorly. You are not looking for *combinations* of columns, so it's the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create an index that unions all the values from firstname, lastname and nickname so that this search (possibly with an adapted query) becomes a single index lookup?

You can do that a few different ways. **All of these work with your query provided,** first on a compound index it will be a single lookup/scan

```
CREATE INDEX f ON t (firstname,lastname,nickname);
```

Or if you don't want to store all of them on the index, you can use a partial index.

```
CREATE INDEX f ON t (whatever) WHERE
  firstname = 'Cassidy'
  OR lastname = 'Cassidy'
  OR nickname = 'Cassidy';
```

> Can I create an index that unions all the values from firstname, lastname and nickname so that this search (possibly with an adapted query) becomes a single index lookup?

A "lookup" isn't a precise term, if you need a seek you'll need different trees for each column that you're indexing. If you need a scan, you can **use an inverted index (GIN)** on the three columns or force it to crawl the btree (or convince it that it's worth it). There is no way to store three distinct cases on a single tree.

See also [`bloom` indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/bloom.html)

Alternatively, if you're looking for were a=b=c, you can create a hash index of the three.

```
CREATE INDEX ON g USING hash( concat(a,b,c) );
```

Comment: I just tried that and it leads to three Bitmap Index Scans and an BitmapOr.

Comment: @AndreKR updated.

Comment: @AndreKR see if GIN provides you the speed needed.

Comment: What is the difference between a "seek" and a "scan" in Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For b-tree/gist: scan crawls the whole index sequentially, seek is o(log n) down the tree? am i wrong? (fixed the concat thing too)

Comment: So are you referring to the difference between an "Index Scan" and a "Bitmap Index Scan"?