# PostgreSQL 9.4 analysis, performance of normal column, indexed column and jsonb key

Tags: index, performance, json, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-performance

If I have a table containing:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(200),
  age INT,
  data JSONB
);
```

and `data` column populated with `{"name": xxx, "age": yyy}`, sometimes `{"name": xxx, "age": yyy, "somethingElse": zzz}`

which one would be faster? querying `test.data->>name` or `test.name` ? and `test.data->>age` or `test.age`?

Could anyone do an analysis for me for those case and case below?

```
INSERT INTO test(name,age,data) 
  SELECT 
      z
    , gs.y
    , ('{"name":"' || z || '","age":' || gs.y || '}')::JSONB
      FROM (SELECT md5(z::text) z, random() AS y FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS gs(z)) AS gs;



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=30412.00..30412.07 rows=30 width=458)
   ->  Sort  (cost=30412.00..31139.32 rows=290928 width=458)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..21819.60 rows=290928 width=458)
```

integer test

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE age < 0.5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=43861.14..43861.22 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=43861.14..44694.47 rows=333333 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..34016.33 rows=333333 width=116)
               Filter: ((age)::numeric < 0.5)



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE (data->>'age')::FLOAT < 0.5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                         QUERY PLAN                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=48861.14..48861.22 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=48861.14..49694.47 rows=333333 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..39016.33 rows=333333 width=116)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'age'::text))::double precision < 0.5::double precision)



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE (data->>'age')::NUMERIC < 0.5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=48861.14..48861.22 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=48861.14..49694.47 rows=333333 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..39016.33 rows=333333 width=116)
               Filter: (((data ->> 'age'::text))::numeric < 0.5)
```

string test

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%aaa%' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=31006.58..31006.66 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=31006.58..31031.83 rows=10101 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..30708.25 rows=10101 width=116)
               Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%aaa%'::text)




EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE data->>name LIKE '%aaa%' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=34464.38..34464.45 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=34464.38..34564.38 rows=40000 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..33283.00 rows=40000 width=116)
               Filter: ((data ->> (name)::text) ~~ '%aaa%'::text)
```

after creating index

```
CREATE INDEX test_name ON test(name);
CREATE INDEX test_age on test(age);



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=60217.45..60217.53 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=60217.45..62717.45 rows=1000000 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..30683.00 rows=1000000 width=116)



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE age < 0.5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=43861.14..43861.22 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=43861.14..44694.47 rows=333333 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..34016.33 rows=333333 width=116)
               Filter: ((age)::numeric < 0.5)



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE name LIKE '%aaa%' ORDER BY random() LIMIT 30;
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=31006.58..31006.66 rows=30 width=116)
   ->  Sort  (cost=31006.58..31031.83 rows=10101 width=116)
         Sort Key: (random())
         ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..30708.25 rows=10101 width=116)
               Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%aaa%'::text)
```

why the index has no effect here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Table definition

Better:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  test_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  age INT,
  name text,
  data JSONB
);
```

Due to **alignment** requirements of the types `integer` and `varchar` / `text` it's better to put the two `int` columns first and together. More:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Also, "age" is a dubious column to begin with. Normally it's better to store a "birthday" or "creation_date" as absolute information, while "age" is rotting quickly.

#### 2. Test data

```
INSERT INTO test(name,age,data) 
SELECT name, age, row_to_json(sub)::jsonb
FROM  (
   SELECT md5(g::text) AS name, (random() * 100)::int AS age
   FROM   generate_series(1,1000000) g
   ) sub;
```

- `row_to_json()` is much more elegant than building the string by hand.
- If you cast `random()` to `integer`, you get `0` or `1`. **Largely useless data** for any kind of test. In particular, indexes are useless with just two distinct common values. Multiplying by 100 to get something halfway useful.

#### 3. Why are indexes not used?

Your btree index:

```
CREATE INDEX test_name ON test(name);
```

is **useless** for `LIKE` queries that are not left-anchored (`name LIKE '%aaa%'`). Details here:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/939860)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)
- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12459689/939860)

Your btree index:

```
CREATE INDEX test_age on test(age);
```

***was useless***, since you only had `0` and `1` in your column `age`, and an idex is typically only used if a small portion (~ below 5 %, it depends) of the table is expected to qualify. Try again with more realistic data.

#### 4. Test method

[`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) only shows query plans. To get actual performance use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or, for most accurate total times: `EXPLAIN ( ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)`.

#### General advice

Columns with scalar values are generally *much* smaller and faster in every respect than document types like `jsonb`. `jsonb` (pg 9.4) has received major improvements over `json`, but this is still true. Queries with predicates on values inside a JSON object are slower than predicates on scalar columns. With optimized (functional) indexes, `jsonb` can get close, but it will never be as fast.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to multiply random with integer.