# What does the Postgres <-> operator do?

Tags: postgresql, operator

I was reading through the [Postgres documentation on materialized views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html) and in one example they use the following:

```
SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY word <-> 'caterpiler' LIMIT 10;
```

I tried to run a similar query on my own database, but I get an error.

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying <-> unknown
```

I (probably) don't need to use the operator, but I'm just curious what it does.

**Notes**:

- I am running the same version as the docs (9.3)
- I did try Googling the question, but Google just ignores the `<->` even if you wrap it in quotes.

Comment: Not quite so. I found this question by googling "postgresql <->"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's supposed to be the "distance" operator from the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE)

> `text <-> text` → `real`  Returns the "distance" between the arguments, that is one minus the `similarity()` value.

The module has to be installed (once per database) with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

More details:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

*Theoretically*, any user with the necessary privileges could create an operator with that operator name using [`CREATE OPERATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html) - but not in the example you link to.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why it didn't work on my database. I see now that the extention is used in the documentation example.