# Postgressql text search: pg_trgm index with order by going very slowly

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.5, like, postgresql-extensions

I have a really slow query(~30 seconds) on a large text search DB that I could really use some help with.

I'm searching for ordered text, in a long file path string. So the path could be: `folder1/cat 123/dog 234`

I'm using `ilike '%search_term_1% %search_term_2%'` to do searches. So `cat dog` would return the result above.

I have a table with two columns:

```
create table file (
  id bigserial primary key,
  path varchar(2048) not null,
  peers integer);
```

I want to do a text search on `path`, and order by `peers desc nulls last`

I've created the following two indices to speed up the queries:

```
create index idx_file_path_tri on file using gin (path gin_trgm_ops);
create index idx_file_peers on file(peers nulls last);
```

Here's the `explain anaylze` results:

```
explain analyze select * from file where path ilike '%cat%' order by peers desc nulls last limit 15;
```

It looks like I need a compound index with the gin, but it won't let me build one based on `peers desc nulls last`...

```
Limit  (cost=7512.09..7512.13 rows=15 width=126) (actual time=342729.147..342729.153 rows=15 loops=1)                      
   ->  Sort  (cost=7512.09..7516.48 rows=1753 width=126) (actual time=342729.144..342729.145 rows=15 loops=1)               
         Sort Key: peers DESC NULLS LAST                                                                                    
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB                                                                          
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on file  (cost=809.59..7469.09 rows=1753 width=126) (actual time=2143.088..342610.395 rows=219
580 loops=1)                                                                                                                
               Recheck Cond: ((path)::text ~~* '%cat%'::text)                                                               
               Heap Blocks: exact=38190                                                                                     
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_file_path_tri  (cost=0.00..809.15 rows=1753 width=0) (actual time=2108.286..2108
.286 rows=223590 loops=1)                                                                                                   
                     Index Cond: ((path)::text ~~* '%cat%'::text)                                                           
 Planning time: 0.328 ms                                                                                                    
 Execution time: 342729.330 ms                                                                                              
(11 rows)
```

Note: the queries go extremely quickly without the `order by`.

Comment: "Text search" is but a phrase. Please define your search requirements exactly. Are you looking for whole words? (Define "word" ...) You might be confusing trigram similarity with Postgres text search. Here is an overview: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684. Also, provide all relevant details for this performance question. Consider instructions here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: No way to reproduce your scenario. Whatever I try to simulate takes only miliseconds. Can you give full definition of table `file`? Does it have very wide columns (for instance, text columns with long texts)? Have you tried performing a `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE` on the table? Which PostgreSQL version are you actually using (9.3 or 9.4)?

Comment: I've added the file table create statement. The path column is full of lots of different data, represented by file path strings. I'm using postgres 9.5.7.

Comment: You have added some info, but essential pieces are still missing. Like cardinalities, typical queries (as single, vague example doesn't define much), avg column size, exact definition of what matches your search, etc. The link I provided has clear instructions. I am not going on another one of those time consuming puzzle hunts. I added another hint to my answer, good luck.

Comment: Your  prose example searches on two terms, but your SQL example searches on one.  Which one is the case?

Answer (score 2):

The core performance problem is the selectivity estimation for the predicate `path ilike '%cat%'`, which is off by a factor of 130:

> (cost=0.00..809.15 **rows=1753** width=0) (actual time=2108.286..2108
>   .286 **rows=223590** loops=1)

Probably leading to a sub-optimal query plan.

In this particular case, Postgres identifies a quarter million rows, just to filter the top 15. A giant waste of time. Depending on missing information, some other query plan (some other query) will be *much* more efficient. Here is a related question with some generic techniques in the answers that apply in similar fashion to your case:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500)

Selectivity estimation for pattern matching is hard, but there have been major improvements in Postgres 9.6. Detailed explanation in this closely related answer:

- [Trigram index for for ILIKE patterns not working as expected](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138288/trigram-index-for-for-ilike-patterns-not-working-as-expected)

Your best course of action *may* be to install a current version of Postgres.

Of course, there may be all kinds of additional problems, your question does not reveal details.

Or you may be using the wrong tool altogether, you did not define what you are trying to search exactly.

---

Concerning:

> It looks like I need a compound index with the gin, but it won't let me build one based on peers desc nulls last ...

Again: essential details like your `CREATE INDEX` command and the resulting error msg are missing. My educated guess: You need to install the additional module [`btree_gin`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gin.html) first. You probably know that by now, since you just commented on this related answer explaining as much:

- [Best index for similarity function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103821/best-index-for-similarity-function/103823#103823)

But don't bother, it probably won't help with your query.

Comment: I've added what I'm searching for, and the file table definition. It turns out the create index command runs : `create index idx_file_path_tri_2 on file using gin (peers, path gin_trgm_ops);`, but the explain path looks exactly like above, with the order by still doing a `top-N heapsort` instead of working on the compound index.

Comment: I'll try to install postgres 9.6, since I'm on 9.5.7 and see if that speeds up my ilike at all.

Answer (score 1):

`GIN` indexes inherently do not support indexable `order by`.

It either needs to find all results which match the ilike using the gin index, and then sort them.  Or it needs to walk through the sortable index in sort order, until it accumulates the LIMIT worth of things which match the ilike.

If you would like to force it to switch to the second mode to see what the performance would be like, you can phrase the restriction like this:

```
path||'' ilike '%cat%'
```

It is theoretically possible that it could walk the sortable index in index order, while also taking an adjunct bitmap of things to filter on.  But that feature is not implemented in PostgreSQL currently.

It might be possible to use the [RUM](https://github.com/postgrespro/rum) index extension for this purpose, but I haven't evaluated it myself for that purpose.

Another possibility would be to use `gin_fuzzy_search_limit` to return incomplete results to those who specify vague queries.

Answer (score 0):

The above posters are correct, postgres will NOT allow you to create a trigram index with an order by as a secondary field. But I finally found a good way to do this, using postgres' materialized views.

Create a materialized view, that orders in your preferred way.

```
create materialized view MY_VIEW as
select * from MY_TABLE
order by ....
```

Then create a trigram index on that view.

```
create index idx_MY_VIEW_tri on MY_VIEW using gin (path gin_trgm_ops);
```

I've found unfortunately that using the `CONCURRENTLY` option, IE, `refresh materialized view concurrently MY_VIEW` won't correctly preserve your preferred sorting order, even though the data will be updated. Only doing so without the `CONCURRENTLY` option will keep the ordering correct.