# Improving performance of count where only result > 0 matters

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, query-performance

I have following query:

```
select count(*) -- rp.tag
from submission 
inner join post rp on submission.id = rp.submission_id 
where user_name = ?1
and lower(rp.tag) like ('%verified%')
and not lower(rp.tag) like ('%unverified%');
```

If the result is greater than 0 I do something in my application for this user.

I run this query against a big list of users and it takes close to an hour to finish the whole process. And I only need to know whether the result is greater than 0.

Is there a way to finish the query early if any of the `rp.tag` match my condition?

Comment: Which table is "user_name" in?

Comment: Assuming `submission.user_name`, or the join would be odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* add `LIMIT 1`, but `LIMIT` is applied *after* aggregation (so after the count). Adding it in the same query level does *nothing* useful, since there is only 1 row left to return anyway: the row count. Would be misleading nonsense.

***If*** you want to go that route, add `LIMIT` in a subquery and count in the outer `SELECT`, like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
   SELECT             -- empty SELECT list
   FROM   submission
   JOIN   ...
   WHERE  ...
   LIMIT 1
   ) sub
```

For this special purpose it's fastest to leave the `SELECT` list empty. `count(*)` only counts the existence of rows without regard to any columns.

You can do that with *any* `LIMIT`, really. To check whether there are at least *N* rows. See:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)

Checking for *N = 1* is just your special case. And while we only care whether *any* rows exist and not how many, [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) is the better, faster tool:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM submission s
   JOIN   post p ON s.id = p.submission_id 
   WHERE  s.user_name = ?
   AND    p.tag ~* 'verified'
   AND    NOT p.tag ~* 'unverified'
   );
```

Without index, `lower(col) LIKE '%something%'` is a bit faster than `col ~* 'something'`. But if your tables are big and performance matters (like your question indicates), you should have matching indexes to begin with, a **trigram index** on `tag` to be precise. Assuming tag is from table `post` (you left room for interpretation there):

```
CREATE INDEX post_tag_gin_trgm_idx ON post USING gin (tag gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then the simpler expression is just as fast. See:

- [LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337500/939860)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

**Depending** on cardinalities and data distribution it might make sense to combine that with `submission_id` in a multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX post_foo_trgm_idx ON post USING gin (submission_id, tag gin_trgm_ops);
```

You'd need the additional module btree_gin for that. See:

- [Best index for similarity function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103821/best-index-for-similarity-function/103823#103823)

And it might make sense to have another multicolumn index on `submission(id, user_name)` - or on `submission(user_name, id)`, again depending on the mentioned details. The first variant is more likely to be useful in case Postgres expects the predicate on `submission.user_name` to be more selective.

(Your handling of tags might be optimized further.)

**Aside:**

> If the result is greater than 0 I do something in my application for this user.

If that *something* is another SQL DML statement, make it a single statement for additional gains. Example:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    bar = 'baz'
WHERE  EXISTS ( ...) -- like above
AND    bar IS DISTINCT FROM 'baz' -- avoid empty updates
```

About the added last line:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

Or you embed the expression in plpgsql code for procedural needs, like demonstrated here:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11892796/939860)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! SELECT EXISTS made a big improvement. However I did not see any improvement using `p.tag  ~* 'verified'` with the index on the column as described. The query runs about 20% faster with the `like` syntax

Comment: @isADon: Yes, like I said, without index, your original expression is faster.  A trigram index is the weapon of choice for the given unanchored patterns. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684 Implementation details depend on additional information: cardinalities, value frequencies, row sizes, clarifications about your schema. And you may need `ANALYZE` between index creation and the query. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/99324/3684