# Can jsonb do fast search by *value* or even a partial value? Other types?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, full-text-search, json

I have a `person` table where arbitrary data must be inserted. Since I'm using Postgres 9.4, `jsonb` appears to be the right choice.

Example data:

```
id: 1, name: "Joe Doe", preferences: { color: "red" , toy: "car"}
id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", preferences: { color: "blue", food: "hamburguer" }
```

The problem is that I need to query it by the variable values, example:

All the people who has "hamburger" on preferences, and partial queries must be possible too, so searching for "burg" must bring me record 2.

Using json functions, I can search for values, as long as I known the key, right? Or there is a fast way to search for the values?

What I'm thinking to do is to create a tsvector column and dump the json to use fulltext search to do the partial queries.

Comment: You'll probably want to maintain a generated column for text search purposes that contains a "flattened" representation of the data. Since you want partial matches you can't use full text search, either; a search for "burg" won't find "hamburger" in fts, it can only do whole words with stemming, and prefix matches. Look at the pg_trgm index support for infix searches. Be aware it's slow.

Comment: It looks like you only need one level of key/value pairs (mo nesting)? And only text strings, no numbers or boolean values?

Comment: Yes, no nesting, but values can be strings, dates, numbers.

Comment: I'm testing Craig's suggestion, created a text column and indexed with pg_trgm, it's fast enough for me so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **Postgres 12** or later consider the SQL/JSON path language. See:

- [Pattern-matching for JSON values: slow EXISTS subquery on materialized view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199288/939860)

---

#### Original answer (for older versions)

I suggest a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with unnested values and a trigram index as search tools.

### [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE)

If you don't need nested values, `hstore` may be even better for you. Use the function [**`svals(hstore)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445274/939860) to unnest `hstore` values.

You need to install the additional module `hstore` once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

- [Key value pair in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034597/939860)

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id int PRIMARY KEY
, name text
, preferences jsonb
);
INSERT INTO person VALUES
  (1, 'Joe Doe', jsonb  '{"toy": "car", "color": "red"}')
, (2, 'Jane Doe', '{"food": "hamburguer", "color": "blue"}')
;
```

#### Materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW person_pref AS
SELECT p.person_id, j.preference        -- just pref
FROM   person p, svals(p.preferences) j(preference);
```

This is an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to the set-returning function `svals()`.

#### Trigram Index

You need to install the additional module `pg_trgm` once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

Then:

```
CREATE INDEX person_pref_trgm_idx ON person_pref
USING gin (preference gin_trgm_ops);
```

Details:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

#### Query

```
SELECT *
FROM   person p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM person_pref pp
   WHERE  pp.person_id = p.person_id
   AND    pp.preference ILIKE '%burg%'
   );
```

This is *fast* for selective search terms.

### [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html)

If you have nested values or [`numeric` or `boolean` values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE), `jsonb` may be more efficient. You can do the same as above with [**`jsonb_each_text(jsonb)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW person_pref AS
SELECT p.person_id, j.preference
FROM  person p, jsonb_each_text(p.preferences) AS j(key, preference);
```

Same index, same query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aad183e962c9d2410c94aa3d841c27c6)*

Comment: I saw another solution using func to extract the jsonb on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692624/using-json-object-values-in-postgresql-gin-index   which solution is better performance wise?

Comment: gotcha! https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136919/effectively-searching-through-entire-1-level-nested-jsonb

Comment: This looks great, however I'm seeing an`exist` clause as suggested above performing really slowly despite the subquery itself executing quickly. I've asked a [question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192458/postgres-slow-exists-subquery-fast-seperatly)

Comment: your answer has saved my day, Thanks @erwin