# Effectively searching through entire 1 level nested JSONB

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.5

Let's say we need to check if a jsonb column contains a particular value matching by a substring in any of the value (non-nested, only first level).

How does one effectively optimize a query to search entire `JSONB` column for each value?

Is there some good alternative to doing `ILIKE %val%` on jsonb datatype casted to text?

```
jsonb_each_text(jsonb_column) ILIKE '%val%'
```

As an example consider this data:

```
SELECT '{"col1": "somevalue", "col2": 5.5, "col3": 2016-01-01, "col4": "othervalue", "col5": "yet_another_value"}'::JSONB
```

How would you go about optimizing a query like that when in need to search for pattern `%val%` in records containing different keys configuration in a column? Is there a better alternative to extracting each key-value pair to text and performing an ILIKE/POSIX search?

**Mainly, I'm looking for a different alternative to unpacking a whole jsonb field into separate key rows with their values as text**.

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486)

Comment: Starting the pattern with `'%'` creates an [*un-anchored search pattern*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187659/2639). There is no way around indexing this without a trigram index. Not sure what you want though from this.

Answer (score 6):

Update: In Postgres 12 or later consider an SQL/JSON path expression. Related:

- [Query JSON array of obejcts against multiple values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130699/query-json-array-of-obejcts-against-multiple-values/130863#130863)

---

For pattern-matching, there is currently (pg 10) no better way with ***standard operators and indexes*** than to unnest values and test each individually. At least, use an efficient `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM jsonb_each_text(jsonb_column) WHERE value ~* 'val');
```

A ***specialized solution*** for this particular use case: concatenate all string values per row with an `IMMUTABLE` function and create a trigram GIN index on the expression. You need the additional module `pg_trgm` installed. Read this first if you are not familiar:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all_value_string(jsonb)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT string_agg(value, '|') FROM jsonb_each_text($1)
$func$;
```

Chose a separator that never interferes with your patterns - '|' in the example.

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_all_value_string_trigram_idx ON tbl
USING GIN (f_all_value_string(jsonb_column) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Query (matching the index):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE f_all_value_string(jsonb_column) ~* 'val';
```

Related:

- [Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/search-for-nested-values-in-jsonb-array-with-greater-operator/202761#202761)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Answer (score 0):

For large volumes of data, perhaps you can cut down on the cost of fulltext search by adding a fulltext GIN index, either for the whole json (`to_tsvector(jsonb_column::text)`) or the output of a function that would extract and concatenates all of its relevant values.

Then you could use the `@@ ts_query()` operator to obtain a reduced subset of likely matches, and search within that subset using `ILIKE` or `~`.