# Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?

Tags: postgresql, index, collation

If I have a text column `name` with a collation, for example `tr-TR`, and I run a query

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

then this will do a seq scan.

If I now create an index

```
CREATE INDEX ON t(name text_pattern_ops)
```

the above query will become a bitmap scan. But there is another technique that will achieve the same result:

```
CREATE INDEX ON t(name COLLATE "C")
```

Are those approaches completely equivalent or are there differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html)

> Note that you should also create an index with the default operator
> class if you want queries involving ordinary `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`
> comparisons to use an index. Such queries cannot use the
> `xxx_pattern_ops` operator classes. (Ordinary equality comparisons can
> use these operator classes, however.) It is possible to create
> multiple indexes on the same column with different operator classes.
> If you do use the C locale, you do not need the `xxx_pattern_ops`
> operator classes, because an index with the default operator class is
> usable for pattern-matching queries in the C locale.

So, the index with `COLLATE "C"` does *everything* a `text_pattern_ops` would do,  plus more which the latter cannot. Like support this query:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE name >= 'z' COLLATE "C";
```

`COLLATE "C"` must be specified explicitly in the query to make the `COLLATE "C"` index applicable (unless you operate with "C" collation to begin with, but then why the index?)

The above query requires the feature of ["per-column collation support"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html) (as does your index). The feature was [added with Postgres 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html). The operator class `text_pattern_ops` is much older and made a lot of sense before Postgres 9.1.

**Since Postgres 9.1 the COLLATE "C" variant is superior** as it is more versatile. The only reason I could think of would be to intentionally *not* support additional use cases for some odd reason. The manual might actually add a deprecation notice for the operator classes `xxx_pattern_ops`.