# PostGIS - indexing - speed up query

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, postgis, pattern-matching

I have this query (called from PHP, hence the `$` variables):

```
SELECT a.name,
      St_AsText(a.geom), 
      b.name AS name_b,
      b.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id
WHERE UNACCENT(LOWER(a.name)) LIKE UNACCENT('$searched%')
ORDER BY a.geom <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT($lat $lon)'::geometry         
LIMIT 2;
```

There is `lower(a.name)` **BTree** index on `a.name`, **GIST** index on `a.geom` and `b.id` is **primary key**

It runs about 40ms for `$searched = "Maria%"`. Now, if I set `$searched = "Mariasomething some%"`, time goes up to 2s.

Why? Can it be speed up or perform in a more stable manner?

Comment: The index on `lower(name)` won't be used for that query. You need an index on `unaccent(lower(name))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unaccent is not IMMUTABLE, it is not allowed as a part of the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

We would have to see table definition, cardinalities and the `EXPLAIN` output to be certain, but the reason is most likely this:

Only your spatial GiST index on `a.geom` can be used. The btree index is not applicable. Postgres walks through the "closest" rows until it finds the first two matching your predicate.

Normally, more restrictive conditions make queries faster, since fewer rows have to be fetched (and sorted). But **not** in this constellation:
Fewer qualifying rows don't help a nearest neighbour search with a small `LIMIT` - au contrair. There are two options:

1. The ["nearest neighbour"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521492/939860) search based on the GiST index - which is fast as long as some of the closest rows qualify - fastest if you remove the `WHERE` clause altogether, try it! It gets increasingly expensive if many rows have to be filtered. Basically: the longer your pattern the more expensive the query.
2. A sequential scan, which has to solve the same problem for selective conditions: filter many rows until finding some candidates. The method is faster, but the *whole table* has to be read, and if more than a few rows are found, the final sort by distance gets expensive.

Basically, Postgres is stuck between a rock and a hard place with this **wicked query**.

### Fix

You would need an index on `unaccent(lower(name))` which is not possible, because `unaccent()` is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`. But you can work around this limitation with an `IMMUTABLE` function wrapper - done right:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860)

The best index still seems tricky and depends on your complete situation.

Since you match **left-anchored patterns**, I would try a separate btree index with the `text_pattern_ops` operator class, using the function `f_unaccent()` outlined in the linked answer above:

```
CREATE INDEX a_name_pattern_idx ON a (f_unaccent(lower(name)) text_pattern_ops);
```

More:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Then:

- Rewrite the `WHERE` condition to match the indexed expression
- Make the wildcard to the right of the expression *explicit* to make it work for prepared statements.
- Don't concatenation text parameters into your query to begin with, that's an invitation for sneaky errors and **SQL injection**. Use a **prepared statement**:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT a.name, ST_AsText(a.geom), b.name AS name_b, b.id
        FROM   a
        LEFT   JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id
        WHERE  f_unaccent(lower(a.name)) LIKE (f_unaccent(lower($1)) || $$%$$)
        ORDER  BY a.geom <-> ST_GeomFromText($$POINT($2 $3)$$, 4326)
        LIMIT  2';

$result = pg_query_params($sql, array($searched, $lat, $lon));
```

I use [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860) to avoid escaping single quotes.

For repeated calls use `pg_prepare` and `pg_execute`. Details:

- [Problems with my attempt to implement an UPSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34580928/939860)

**Or** you could try a GiST index - a multicolumn, functional GiST index combining a PostGis spatial GiST index and a functional trigram GiST index. I didn't test that combination, yet.

You need to install [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) first. Instructions:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

```
CREATE INDEX a_special_gist_idx ON a
USING gist (f_unaccent(lower(name)) gist_trgm_ops, geom);
```

I put `f_unaccent(lower(name))` first because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html):

> A multicolumn GiST index can be used with query conditions that
> involve any subset of the index's columns. Conditions on additional
> columns restrict the entries returned by the index, but the condition
> on the first column is the most important one for determining how much
> of the index needs to be scanned. A GiST index will be relatively
> ineffective if its first column has only a few distinct values, even
> if there are many distinct values in additional columns.