# Postgres HAVING ilike any wildcard in array_agg

Tags: postgresql, query, aggregate, pattern-matching, like

I need a filter where the input value is similar to any value in an aggregate, using `ilike` and wildcards. My attempt at a query so far is:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_agg(vo.name)
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_variation pv
ON p.id = pv.product_id
LEFT JOIN variation_option vo
ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING $1 ilike any(array_agg('%' || vo.name || '%'));
```

But it doesn't work. It gets even more complicated: ideally, I'd be able to input an array of strings, where any of them are similar to the aggregate. Any tips?

I realize this kind of works, just not as I need it to. The input value should be able to be a partial match for any of the array elements, but it is the other way around. The wild card would need to be in the input value.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but it is the other way around. The wild card would need to be in the inputted value.

Yes, it's backwards, but `ILIKE` (internally operator `~~*`) nor the alternative regexp operator `~*` have commutators. I.e., you can't turn the expression around, can't switch left and right operand. See:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_operator WHERE oprname  IN ('~~*', '~*');
```

`oprcom = 0` means no commutator. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-operator.html)

The right operand of (`I`)`LIKE` is a *pattern*, so switching is impossible. And the `ANY` construct only goes one way. Dead end. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860)

You can still turn it around using a **different tool**: the aggregate function [`bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_agg(vo.name)
FROM   product           p
JOIN   product_variation pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
JOIN   variation_option  vo ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
GROUP  BY p.id
HAVING bool_or(vo.name ILIKE ('%' || $1 || '%'));
```

Also using plain `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, which would be pointless in view of the later filter.

> ideally, I'd be able to input an array of strings

Now that's also possible for an **input array**:

```
...
HAVING bool_or(vo.name ~* ANY($1));
```

`$1` being of type `text[]` or an array literal like `'{foo, bar}'`. I chose the regexp operator as we don't need leading and trailing `%` with it.

Since `$1` is a *pattern* (or an array of patterns), as mentioned above, you may want to escape characters with special meaning (per array element). See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45741630/939860)

If your input is *selective*, meaning only very few products actually qualify, then an alternative formulation with `EXISTS` might be faster - in combination with a trigram index on `vo.name`. See:

- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/how-is-like-implemented/10856#10856)

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX variation_option_name_gin_trgm_idx ON variation_option USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, array_agg(vo.name)
FROM   product           p
JOIN   product_variation pv ON p.id = pv.product_id
JOIN   variation_option  vo ON pv.variation_option_id = vo.id
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT -- list can be empty
   FROM   variation_option vo1
   WHERE  vo1.id = pv.variation_option_id
   AND    vo1.name ILIKE ('%' || $1 || '%')
-- AND    vo1.name ~* ANY($1)  -- for array input
   )
GROUP  BY p.id;
```

Related:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)